# Is it possible to put a function declaration within an unnamed namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a file with a set of functions. For one of the functions, I want to write a helper function which basically takes a char * and skips all whitespaces.

Here's how I thought it should be done:

```
namespace {
    const int kNotFound = -1;

    void SkipWhitespace(const char *s); // forward declaration - doesn't seem to work?
}

void foo(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    // do some stuff

    SkipWhitespace(s1);
    SkipWhitespace(s2);

    // continue with other stuff
}

void SkipWhitespace(const char *s) {
    for (; !isspace(s); ++s) {}
}
```

But this gives me a compiler error. Do I need to put the definition within the unnamed namespace?

Comment: You wrote const char s* down the listing. It's wrong. -> char *s

Comment: you'll also want to make the function 'void SkipWhitespace(const char*&s)'

Comment: you're getting an error because of a typo in SkipWhitespace definition. Should be void SkipWhitespace(const char *s)

Comment: Was only a typo in the posted source.

Comment: @Chris Thx. So I pass in a reference of the pointer, so that it doesn't get copied, right?

Comment: Yes. You want "SkipWhiteSpace" to return the pointer adjusted past the whitespace.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to *define* it in the anonymous namespace as well:

```
namespace {
    ...
    void SkipWhitespace(const char *s); // forward declaration - doesn't seem to work?
}

void foo(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    ...
}

namespace {
    void SkipWhitespace(const char s*) {
        for (; !isspace(s); ++s) {}
    }
}
```

But unless there is a cyclic dependency, I'm not sure what the value of this is. Just declare and define the function in one go.

Comment: I like when you can read source code upside down, i.e. when function A calls function B, function B also follows function A in the source code. In Java this is no problem but I guess in C++ defining it directly is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

An unnamed namespace behaves as if it was replaced with a namespace with a uniquely generated name immediately followed by a using directive.

This means that your function declaration belongs to a namespace exactly as if the namespace actually had a name. As such, its definition should live in the same namespace : either simultaneously declare and define the function, or add an enclosing `namespace {}` around the definition (which works because all occurrences of the unnamed namespace in a translation unit refer to the same namespace).

```
namespace {

void SkipWhitespace(const char s*) {
    for (; !isspace(s); ++s) {}
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to see this topic as well:

[Superiority of unnamed namespace over static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422507/superiority-of-unnamed-namespace-over-static/4422554#4422554)

BTW, why this function:

```
void SkipWhitespace(const char *s);
```

Why not this:

```
void SkipWhitespace(std::string &s);
```

??

Comment: Sry I didn't mention that it was a homework assignment, where using the std::string class is prohibited.

Comment: @Helper lol, a C++ assignment with std::string prohibited.  Obviously, you have some fun courses...

Comment: Yeah, sadly it's one of those weird C/C++ course where you end up don't knowing either language :-(.

Comment: @stefaanv : this is the usual situation in India here where students are taught C in the name of C++.  But what happened to Germany? I didn't expect it.

Comment: @Nawaz: obviously off-topic, but you got me interested: what happened in my neighbour-country that you didn't expect.  The media hasn't informed us yet.  Or are you talking about the Amsterdam scandal (Holland)?

Comment: @stefaanv : No, I'm not talking about anything of that sort. I'm just concerned about (in fact "worried" about) the education and the educators here in India. I graduated from a top institute of the country, yet I started knowing the real C+++ when I joined communities such as this, and when I came across books like Modern C++ Design by Andrei Alexandrescu. Now, I feel that I just wasted my years while knowing C in the name of C++. Even that C never talked anything about undefined, implementation defined, unspecified, and so on. Nothing. Such a waste of time!

Comment: @Nawaz: Oh I see, actually it's not that different over here (eventhough C/C++ wasn't even thought at the time), but we didn't went much further then the available language elements and constructs and some basic exercises.

Comment: @stefaanv : Hmm. I see. But anyway, now I'm getting what I always wished for. Just wish me good luck. :-)