# Can a function be defined in global namespace if it is declared in an anonymous namespace?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang, language-lawyer

In production code I found this in a .cpp file:

```
namespace
{
    void foo(); // declared in anonymous namespace, defined below
}

void bar() // declared in corresponding .h file, defined here
{
    ::foo(); // call foo
}

void ::foo() // intended to refer to the anonymous foo above
{
}
```

We are using Visual Studio 2017. I stumbled over this because intellisense gave me a warning for `foo` that it could not find the function definition.
However, it compiles and links without errors and the code does what it is supposed to do.

I godbolted it and found that gcc and clang reject this code for the same reason that intellisense gave me a warning for.

So my question is: **Which compiler is correct and why?**

---

Furthermore, out of interest I added another declaration of `foo` to the global namespace, like so:

```
namespace
{
    void foo();
}

void foo(); // another declaration

void bar()
{
    ::foo(); // which foo will be called?
}

void ::foo() // which foo will be defined?
{
}
```

Now, gcc gives me an error:

> error: explicit qualification in declaration of 'void foo()'

Clang compiles it, but gives me a warning:

> warning: extra qualification on member 'foo' [-Wextra-qualification]

And msvc compiles it just fine.

Again, which compiler - if any - is correct here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [cppreference page on unnamed namespaces](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Unnamed_namespaces):

> This definition is treated as a definition of a namespace with unique
>   name and a using-directive in the current scope that nominates this
>   unnamed namespace.

So an "anonymous" namespace is not the global namespace, nor is it even unnamed. Rather, it has a compiler-provided unique name. So `::foo()` is *not* the function in your anonymous namespace. MSVC is incorrect here.

And [you can't define your anonymous namespace function outside its anonymous namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4428589/10077).

Comment: Makes sense, but then why can I call it via `::foo()` if it is not that one?

Comment: I can. Even with gcc

Comment: I'm guessing that's the effects of the implicit `using namespace`, but it will take a better language lawyer than me to explain it.

Comment: @sebrockm You can ask a new question.