# Why a global variable is defined as static in this C program?

Tags: c

I'm trying to learn C using [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_storage_classes.htm) tutorial. There is an example there that the author is tried to learn us what `static` storage class is.

This is that example :

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function declaration */
void func(void);

static int count = 5; /* global variable */

main()
{
   while(count--)
   {
      func();
   }
   return 0;
}
/* function definition */
void func( void )
{
   static int i = 5; /* local static variable */
   i++;

   printf("i is %d and count is %d\n", i, count);
}
```

My question is: Why he/she is defined `count` as `static`? In the other words, what is the difference between the above program and the following program?

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function declaration */
void func(void);

int count = 5; /* global variable */

main()
{
   while(count--)
   {
      func();
   }
   return 0;
}
/* function definition */
void func( void )
{
   static int i = 5; /* local static variable */
   i++;

   printf("i is %d and count is %d\n", i, count);
}
```

**I mean, when we must use the  first program and when we must use the second one?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4725234/3049655

Comment: You should also *read code* e.g. study the source code of *existing free software*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining your `count` as a global variable or a `static` one does not matter in your particular example (where each program has only one source file, i.e. one [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29)). But it does matter for `i` (which, without the `static` keyword, would become an automatic local variable), since it is declared *inside* a function. However, it would matter a big lot for any program made of several translation units (linked together to make the executable).

If you define a `count` global variable in two different translation units (i.e. in `foo1.c` and `foo2.c`) the linker would complain against multiple definitions (when you build your `foo` executable from `foo1.o` & `foo2.o` with `gcc foo1.o foo2.o -o foo` on your Linux system); if you defined a `static int count;` variable both in `foo1.c` and in `foo2.c` it is ok (but then you have *two* synonymous variables, each having its own address, and each implicitly initialized to 0; IMHO this is often poor taste, because it makes the source code less readable).

As an exception, you can declare *without explicitly initializing it* a global variable of the same name in two different translation units. The name refers to the *same* and *unique* global (initialized to 0).

So having

```
// in file foo1.c
int globalcount; // a global variable *declaration*
```

and

```
// in file foo2.c
int globalcount; // a global variable *declaration*
```

is the same as having

```
// in file foo1.c
int globalcount = 0; // a global variable *definition* with initialization
```

and

```
// in file foo2.c
extern int globalcount;  // an external variable declaration
```

<sup>Actually, that external declaration should usually be in some header file `foo.h` which gets `#include`-d by both `foo1.c` & `foo2.c`.</sup>

Therefore, static variables (of the main program) are also invisible by [plugins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plug-in_%28computing%29). Read more about [visibility attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) (on Linux) to make a variable visible only by a single plugin or shared library (but not outside it).

Read wikipage on [linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29) & [dynamic linkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) then Levine's book [*linkers and loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linker/)

Practically speaking, I would suggest to use unique names for non-local variables (both global and static ones), for readability and convenience (since it is easy to [`grep`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) them); but sometimes you might want to have a few `static` variables with the same name in different compilation units. If you do, I suggest to comment why, and have some consistent naming conventions.

Look for examples in some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) coded in C.

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer. What happens if I define `int count` in foo1.c and `static int count = 5` in foo2.c?

Comment: Then in `foo2.c` you'll see the static variable. But you should not code this way (it is confusing for human developers and make your code unreadable)

Comment: I think your answer need a small refinement. Here : _... if you defined a `static int count;` variables both ..._ I think I must initialize static variable in the point of definitions. right?

Comment: No, you need to declare static variables. Without initialization (and contrarily to `auto` or local variables) they are initialized to zero or -for pointers- to `NULL`

Answer (score 3):

static for a global variable makes it global only to that file (compilation unit). It will not be accessible from other files (compilation units)