# What does "static enum" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, enums, static

I recently came across this:

```
static enum Response{
    NO_ERROR=0,
    MISSING_DESCRIPTOR,
    ...
};
```

It compiles and works under Microsoft VS2005. However, I'm not sure what the 'static' modifier is supposed to do. Is it any different from the following?

```
enum Response {
    NO_ERROR=0,
    MISSING_DESCRIPTOR,
    ...
};
```

Comment: Is it in a header file or a cpp file?

Comment: Just tried it in Visual Studio 2008 and it compiles without complaint there too. Weird.

Comment: To clarify
its in a .cpp file and there is no variable name between } and ;
It is not a variable declaration.

Comment: The msdn page detailing how to declare an `enum` in VS2005, VS2008, and VS2010 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e.aspx) makes no mention of `static`. Probably a bug that it allows it then.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

That exact code, with just the ellipsis removed, is not valid C++.  You can't use the `static` storage class specifier in an `enum` declaration; it doesn't make any sense there (only objects, functions, and anonymous unions can be declared `static`).

You can, however, declare an `enum` and a variable all in one declaration:

```
static enum Response {
    NO_ERROR = 0,
    MISSING_DESCRIPTOR
} x;
```

The `static` here applies to `x` and it is effectively the same as if you said:

```
enum Response { 
    NO_ERROR = 0,
    MISSING_DESCRIPTOR
};

static Response x;
```

Comment: My guess would be that since this was valid in C, msvc just forgot to implement this properly when evolving into a c++ compiler

Answer (score 14):

Surprisingly you can put other *decl-specifiers* in there too.
This compiles fine in VS2008:

```
auto const enum TestEnum {
    Why,
    Does
};

register volatile enum TestEnum2 {
    This,
    Work
};
```

But it makes no sense at all :)

I suspect the problem here is in the parsing, because code like this:

```
enum TestEnum3 { Hello, World };  // Define enum
enum TestEnum3 x = World;         // Use enum
```

Could also be written as:

```
enum TestEnum3 { Hello, World } x = World; // Define and use enum.
```

Interestingly, I notice if you do this in VS2008:

```
enum TestEnum3 { Hello, World };
const enum TestEnum3 e3 = World;
const enum TestEnum4 { F, M, L } e4 = F;

e3 = Hello; // error C2166: l-value specifies const object (Good!)
e4 = M;     // NO ERROR here though - why?
```

So they are not equivalent as in the `TestEnum4` case it seems to be throwing away the `const` *decl-specifier*. All very odd.

Comment: According to this, it seems they really have a bug in the parser then. Thanks for this example with 'auto const'.

Answer (score 8):

```
static enum Response { /*... */ };
```

You cannot define `static` enum in C++.  `static` can only be the *variable* of the enum, not the *type* itself!

Compiling your code with `GCC` version `4.3.4`, it gives this error:

> prog.cpp:7: error: a storage class can
>   only be specified for objects and
>   functions

See yourself online at ideone: http://www.ideone.com/cI1bt

I think that says it all.

--

However, if you want to limit the *type* `enum Response` in it's own translation unit, then you can use unnamed namespace. Have a look at this topic:

[Superiority of unnamed namespace over static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422507/superiority-of-unnamed-namespace-over-static)

Comment: Apparently, in this particular flavour of C++, one can do that. However, your comment abou the unnamed namespace is very interesting, thanks!

Comment: @Marcin: No, you cannot do that. VS2005 incorrectly compiles that. Read James' reply; he explained when you can write `static` enum and more importanly what exactly it means. It makes the *variable* static, not the *type* itself.

Answer (score 2):

**Standard**

The [C++11 N3337 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) Annex C 7.1.1 says that it was allowed in C but had no effect, and became illegal in C++:

> Change: In C ++, the static or extern specifiers can only be applied to names of objects or functions.
>   Using these specifiers with type declarations is illegal in C ++. In C, these specifiers are ignored when used
>   on type declarations. Example:

```
static struct S {    // valid C, invalid in C++
  int i;
};
```

> Rationale: Storage class specifiers don’t have any meaning when associated with a type. In C ++, class
>   members can be declared with the static storage class specifier. Allowing storage class specifiers on type
>   declarations could render the code confusing for users.

And like `struct`, `enum` is also a type declaration.

**Implementation rationale**

Enum definitions have no storage, and do no generate symbols in object files like variables and functions. Just try compiling and decompiling:

```
struct S { int i; int j; };
int i;
```

with:

```
g++ -c main.c
nm main.o
```

and you will see that there is no `S` symbol, but there is an `i` symbol.

When the compiler sees an enum values, it just inserts it literally into the compiled code. This only works of course because they are compile-time constants.

They must therefore be included on header files.

See also:

- related question for `static struct` in C: [Why and when to use static structures in C programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259830/why-and-when-to-use-static-structures-in-c-programming)

Answer (score 1):

### ***In C#:***

The ';' is optional for backwards compatibility after the enum block.  It does **not** allow for such semantics in that language for named types.  static, public, etc. have special consideration.  Namespace cannot contain members such as fields or methods.

Requires tag:

```
ArgTypes var = ArgTypes.CUT;
```

---

### ***In C/C++:***

Requires ';' at the end of enum block.
For global namespace variables, enumerations, etc.  **static** is by default.

```
int type;

typedef enum {
  TOKENIZE,
  CUT
} ArgTypes;
type = TOKENIZE;  /* <ArgTypes>::TOKENIZE */
type = ArgTypes::CUT;

// Recommended Use
enum ArgTypes {
  TOKENIZE,
  CUT
};  /* Same as above */

enum Test {
  TOKENIZE,
  CUT
} ArgTypes;
type = ArgTypes::TOKENIZE;
type = CUT;   /* Assign type =>  <Test>.CUT */
type = Test::CUT;

enum {
  TOKENIZE,
  CUT
} ArgTypes;  /* Unamed.. requires tag */
type = TOKENIZE; /* <unamed>.TOKENIZE=0 => #define TOKENIZE 0*/
type = ArgTypes::TOKENIZE;  /* ** ERROR ** */
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure why static was used or why it even compiles.  Should just be enum Response.
Enumerators are not static data.