# Static struct warning useless storage class specifier in empty declaration

Tags: c, struct, static

```
  static struct astr {
          int a;
  };

  static const struct astr newastr = {
          .a = 9,
  };
```

I get: **warning: useless storage class specifier in empty declaration**

If I change it to

```
  static struct astr {
          int a;
  } something;
```

then the warning will be fixed.

The following also does not give that warning

```
  struct astr {
          int a;
  };

  static const struct astr newastr = {
          .a = 9,
  };
```

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: What would be the purpose of a `static` specifier for the struct declaration?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7259830/11336762

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting warnings when you have structure definitions without declaring any variables.  For example, the following will give a warning:

```
static struct s {
    int a;
};
```

This is equivalent to:

```
struct s {
    int a;
};
```

It defines the structure `s` but does not declare any variables.  I.e., there is no storage associated with it, so there's nothing to apply the `static` to.

But if you do:

```
static struct s {
    int a;
} x;
```

Then there is no warning because you're declaring variable `x` in addition to defining structure `s`, so the `static` applies to `x`.

Similarly, if `struct s` has been previously defined, you can do:

```
static struct s x;
```

with no warning.  And of course, you can optionally supply an initializer if desired.