# Static enum usage in c

Tags: c

I have searched the static usage on enums in c and then I am posting this topic here. I am a tester and I need to test the **enum datatype for local,static ,global scope** by writing a simple program.

A simple static variable can be tested easily, similarly **I need to test static enum datatype.**

I have written a simple code. Need your help guys.

```
#include<stdio.h>

enum day {sun=1,mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat};
static enum direction {UP,DOWN,RIGHT,LEFT};

int static_enum()
{
    static enum direction dir = UP;
    printf("dir = %d\n",dir);
    dir++;
}


int main()
{
    printf("\nsun = %d mon = %d tue = %d wed = %d thurs = %d fri = %d sat = %d\n",sun,mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat);
    enum day fri = 25;
    // now friday gets modified from 21 to 25 becasue we have re-assigned the value
    printf("\nfri = %d\n",fri);
    // now saturday will still have value 22
    printf("\nsat = %d\n",sat);
    printf("\n"); 
    static_enum();
    static_enum();
        return 0;
}
```

Let me know if the code tests the static functionality of enum data type.
Thank you

Note : the topics I searched landed me in either C# or java.

Comment: The `static enum` code in question doesn't look valid to me.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971436/c-what-does-static-enum-mean

Comment: The code successfully compiles in gcc under linux and on codepad

Comment: There is plenty of code which is invalid yet still compiles.  Anyway, let's say it's valid.  Then, `static` has no effect.  You can safely remove it.

Comment: Thank you very much John Zwinck. I changed the code little bit and I could see the difference. Inside static enum() I removed the static keyword in static enum direction dir. The ouput I get is dir = 0, dir=0. But if I retain the keyword static then the output is dir=0 and dir = 1. I think this is sufficient for me to test the static functionality here.

Comment: What is your question? Do you not understand `static`?

Comment: yes david, I do understand the keyword static. But my use case is to check the static enum functionality in a code.

Comment: you can ignore the printf statement in main functions.Just concentrate static_enum() functions.

Comment: @vk41286 Then you removed the wron `static`. Omit the `static` in `static enum direction {UP,DOWN,RIGHT,LEFT};` and keep it inside the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *static* storage class is related to the linkage and storage of an *object*. It doesn't really have anything to do with the *type* of the object.

Below is an explanation of what (I think) your program is doing:

---

```
enum day {sun=1,mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat};
```

This declares an enumerated type with the tag name `day`, and also defines a number of enumeration constants and their values.

```
static enum direction {UP,DOWN,RIGHT,LEFT};
```

This declares an enumerated type with the tag name `direction`, and also defines a number of enumeration constants and their values.

The `static` *storage-class* is meaningless here, because you are not defining (allocating storage) for an object.

```
int static_enum()
{
    static enum direction dir = UP;
    printf("dir = %d\n",dir);
    dir++;
}
```

This defines a block-scope object named `dir` of type `enum direction`. The `static` *storage-class* means that the object will be allocated and initialized at program startup, and that it will retain its last stored value between function calls.

```
int main()
{
    printf("\nsun = %d mon = %d tue = %d wed = %d thurs = %d fri = %d sat = %d\n",sun,mon,tue,wed,thur,fri,sat);
```

This will output the values of the enumeration constants.

```
enum day fri = 25;
```

This defines a block-scope object named `fri` of type `enum day`, initialized with the value `25`. The enumeration constant also named `fri` will not be visible anymore within this block (unless you re-declare `enum day`).

```
// now friday gets modified from 21 to 25 becasue we have re-assigned the value
printf("\nfri = %d\n",fri);
```

This outputs the value of the *object* `fri`, **not** the value of the *enumeration constant* `fri`. Nothing has been modified.

```
// now saturday will still have value 22
printf("\nsat = %d\n",sat);
```

This outputs the value of the enumeration constant `sat`, as expected.

```
printf("\n"); 
static_enum();
static_enum();
    return 0;
}
```

---

One might wonder why the language allows the `static` *storage-class* in a declaration that does not define (allocate storage for) an object. I *think* this is just a syntactical convenience due to the way that declarations and definitions share the same syntax. The C syntax allows you to pile any number of *storage-class*, *type-specifier*, *type-qualifier*, *function-specifier* and *alignment-specifier* in any order in a declaration. However, many combinations are disallowed or cause *undefined behavior* according to various semantic sections of the C standard. I don't *think* there is anything that prohibits the meaningless `static` keyword in the declaration of `direction`.

Comment: I'm quite sure there isn't anything disallowing the useless storage-class specifier. `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors` gives a warning, not an error (`-pedantic-errors` is at least intended to also catch compile-time UB).