# C++ declaring static enum vs enum in a class

Tags: c++, class, enums, static, nested

What's the difference between the `static enum` and `enum` definitions when defined inside a class declaration like the one shown below?

```
class Example
{
     Example();
     ~Example();

     static enum Items{ desk = 0, chair, monitor };
     enum Colors{ red = 0, blue, green };
}
```

Also, since we are defining types in a class, what do we call them?  By analogy if I define a variable in a class, we call it a member variable.

Comment: What compiler are you using? It would surprise me if this compiles, as `static` wouldn't make much sense here.

Comment: If you're using C++11, consider using `enum class`.

Comment: The `static` specifier isn't valid in an enum declaration. This shouldn't compile.

Comment: @swalog I'm using Visual Studio 2012.  Do you know where I can find the compiler being used?  I see the Platform Toolset is Visual Studio 2012 (v110).

Comment: @swalog I opened a Visual Studio command prompt and ran cl.exe.  It says I'm using Microsost (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 for X86.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: what does "static enum" mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971436/c-what-does-static-enum-mean)

Comment: Also see [What does “static enum” mean in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4971436/608639)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`static` cannot be applied to `enum` declarations, so your code is invalid.

From N3337, *§7.1.1/5 **[dcl.stc]***

> The `static` specifier can be applied only to names of variables and functions and to anonymous unions ...

An `enum` declaration is none of those.

You can create an instance of the `enum` and make that `static` if you want.

```
class Example
{
     enum Items{ desk = 0, chair, monitor };
     static Items items; // this is legal
};
```

In this case `items` is just like any other [static data member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Static_data_members).

---

This is an [MSVC bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/927577/storage-classes-allowed-on-enum-declarations); from the linked bug report it seems the compiler will allow both `static` and `register` storage specifiers on `enum` declarations. The bug has been closed as fixed, so maybe the fix will be available in VS2015.

Comment: I do wonder, though, why `static` here isn't taken to apply to the set of 0 data members declared in this declaration. After all, if you did `static enum Items { ... } item;`, it would be valid.

Comment: @Brian I don't understand what you mean by *set of 0 data members*. There either is a data member or there isn't, and if there isn't then what would the storage specifier apply to?

Comment: Well because to have a set of 0 data members, you have to actually create a set to begin with. Using `enum` is like describing what a set would look like if you were to create one. It's not actually creating anything, though, as opposed to your example.

Comment: nvm, I found the right quote from the standard: "If a storage-class-specifier appears in a decl-specifier-seq, there can be
no typedef specifier in the same decl-specifier-seq and the init-declarator-list of the declaration shall not
be empty (except for an anonymous union declared in a named namespace or in the global namespace,
which shall be declared static (9.5))."

Comment: When you define an enum, struct, class, or union, the *init-declarator-list* is optional: if you include it then you declare 1 or more variables, and if you don't include it then you declare 0 variables. So it would seem that the grammar allows `static` to be applied to an enum declaration that doesn't declare any variables / data members---if an enum declaration can declare 0 variables of the type then why can't it declare 0 static variables of that type? But the standard explicitly forbids this, so I'm now satisfied that gcc and clang are correct.

Answer (score 0):

`static` is a C++ storage specifier. It means the value of this member of the class is the same for all instances of the class. Nothing special about enums here.

EDIT: Even the `static` tag wiki has an explanation. On exactly this topic.

EDIT2: Oh, I've misread your code. There's no static enum. You can have a static variable of an enum type that holds a value.

Comment: An `enum` is no variable.

Comment: yes, but a variable that stores the state encoded in an enum is.

Comment: But he is not asking about those.

Comment: @BaummitAugen: 1. cool handle. ENTirely cool. 2. yep, realized my mistake.