# static struct in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, syntax

```
static struct K {  int x; };
```

Is this valid in C and C++?

Comment: Why not just try it and see? When you find out that it _isn't_ ask what your error is.

Comment: You have no access to a compiler or something?

Comment: @Darin these days everyone who has access to internet has access to compiler: http://ideone.com/YqWd8

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question. What one compiler accepts, another may reject, and this doesn't really help to work out whether it's valid C and C++.

Comment: @Brone In this case, wouldn't any reasonable C compiler accept it and any reasonable C++ compiler reject it? It's certainly a reasonable question; I just get tired of getting excited and then clicking on a link for a question the OP could have answered on their own in about 30 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valid in C. Ill-formed in C++

In C++, specifiers extern/static can only be applied to names of objects or functions

Check out

**C.1.5**  Clause 7: `declarations` (7.1.1) ISO C++03

---

Answer (score 8):

In C, it's valid but **useless**.

In C++ it's invalid. You can only specify storage class for objects and functions.

Answer (score 2):

No... That is not valid in C++. An alternative is (C++) : unnamed namespace

```
namespace 
{
   struct K {  int x; };
}
```

See this related topic:

[Superiority of unnamed namespace over static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422507/superiority-of-unnamed-namespace-over-static)

Answer (score 1):

http://ideone.com/YqWd8

http://ideone.com/XtHYy