# static keyword useless in namespace scope?

Tags: c++, static, namespaces, scope

```
namespace N
{
   static int x = 5;
}
```

What could be the importance/use-cases of declaring having a static variable at namespace scope?

Comment: I believe that the use of `static` is discouraged; use unnamed namespaces instead.

Comment: @ereOn: Not really. C++03 had deprecated its usage, but C++11 has undeprecated it. Why? Because its useful in some way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Annex D (Compatibility features) [C++03]

> D2: The use of the static keyword is deprecated when declaring objects in namespace scope.

Use unnamed namespaces instead as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422507/superiority-of-unnamed-namespace-over-static) post.

static keyword imparts internal linkage to variables/objects in C as well as in C++ in namespace scope as others have mentioned in their posts.

P.S:
Thie feature has been **undeprecated** as per the latest draft (n3290). In n3225 `§7.3.1.1/2` is present but striked out.

Comment: +1, Also, while there is no particular reason why this cannot be done with unnamed namespaces, some compilers provide more diagnostics for `static` linkage functions (like warnings when the symbol is unused in the translation unit)

Answer (score 42):

`static` variable at namespace scope (global or otherwise) has *internal* linkage. That means, it cannot be accessed from other translation units. It is *internal* to the translation unit in which it is declared.

Comment: This is a better answer, as it explains what `static` does in namespace scope.  It doesn't do nothing, and it's not useless.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Nawaz's answer: static keyword is not totally useless in namespaces : it defines that the variable is of internal linkage to the translation unit.

For example : 
header.h

```
namespace test{
    static int i = 5;//definition is here.And there will be no multiple definition!
    void set_i();
    void print_i();
}
```

header.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include "iostream"
void test::set_i()
{
    i = 10;
    return;
}

void test:print_i()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "print_i is " << i << endl;
    return;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
#include "iostream"
using std::cout;
int main()
{
    test::i = 20;
    test::set_i();
    cout << "i is " << test::i << endl; 
    test::print_i();
    return 0;
}
```

Use `g++ -std=c++11 header.cpp main.cpp` to compile it, and you won't get `multiple definition error`.If you remove the `static` keyword and compile it, it is definitely `multiple definition error`. And please do run the program and observe the result and you may be surprised.

`static` keyword makes every cpp implementation file(translation unit) which includes the interface header that contains namespace declaration has a internal-linkage copy of the static variable. So even you define that variable in namespace, if it is `static` keyworded, there will be no multiple definition error.(The same for `const` with no `extern` preceding it which define variable of internal linkage, and that's how macros can be discarded in C++) So the saying that variables defined in namespace are implicitly static is wrong and static are not totally useless in namespace. Because every translation unit have one copy of that variable, space is consumed.

However, unnamed namespace can make class declaration inside it inaccessible from other translation unit while `static` keyword can not "attribute" a class, so that is one advantage of unnamed namespace. Besides, you can use unnamed namespace in nested namespace for variable access restriction. Unnamed namespace are designed for protecting locality rather than offering interface.

Answer (score 1):

C++ Standard §7.3.1.1/2:

> The use of the static keyword is
>   deprecated when declaring objects in a
>   namespace scope (see annex D); the
>   unnamed-namespace provides a superior
>   alternative.

Unless the unnamed namespace provides a superior alternative in the future Standard [it will be undeprecated](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1012) to achieve C compatibility.

Comment: Hasn't this been undeprecated in 2011?

Comment: I believe the C++0x standard un-deprecates `static` in this context, does it not?

Comment: In the last draft this paragraph is present but striked out , so I'm not sure.

Comment: Interesting. I guess you can't take anything for granted with a standard that hasn't been finalized.

Comment: Can someone post a link to the latest draft? I'm b*ggered if I can work it out from the website!

Comment: @Neil : As per n3290 this feature has been undeprecated. In n3225 I could see this paragraph striked out.

Comment: @Prasoon Can you post a link to the draft - my web-foo seems to have gone into decline.

Comment: In the last draft I have handy (from 29 March, 2010), this sentence is still present, albeit in a modified form: the word "objects" has been replaced by "variables".  (Maybe in a later draft?)

Comment: @Neil : Here is the link : http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2011/n3290.pdf

Comment: @Neil: FWIW, whenever I need it I just go to the [tag's info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b0x/info), where I hope someone else who can find that stuff has linked it.

Comment: @James the link prassoon gives is 11-April-2011 and it is not deprecated in that.

Comment: @James I seem to remember a comment from BS that deprecation was a bad idea in the first place because it damaged C compatibility. And I've always preferred static to anonymous namespaces myself.

Comment: @Neil OK.  I understand BS' comment.  With regards to preferences: what do you do about class definitions, which can't be declared static?

Comment: @James Classes have TU scope by default, don't they?

Comment: @Neil Scope isn't an issue; `static` doesn't affect scope.  "Classes" (that is: the name of the class, and the names of all of its members) have external linkage unless they are local (defined in a function).  Thus, if I define `class C { public: C(); };` in my translation unit, and you do the same, `C::C` refers to the same entity in both.  And if we both define it, we'll likely get a duplicate definition when linking.  (Formally, it's undefined behavior.)  And there's no way you can make `static` apply to a class; that's really why unnamed namespaces were introduced.

Comment: @James Yes - I don't know what was going through my mind there!

Answer (score 0):

Same as that of declaring a static in a global namespace but just local to a particular namespace.

Answer (score 0):

What others already said, with an additional subtlety: static introduces internal linkage, and anonymous namespaces do not.