# Singleton vs Static Variables

Tags: c++

I am asking because I am curious while studying the singletone pattern.

I want to know the difference between singletone pattern and static variable.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
};

static A* a;
```

This

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    Singleton() {}
    ~Singleton() {}
private:
    static Singleton* m_Singleton;
    
public:
    static Singleton* GetInstance()
    {
        if (m_Singleton == nullptr)
        {
            m_Singleton = new Singleton();
        }
        return m_Singleton;
    }
    static void DestroyInstance()
    {
        if (m_Singleton == nullptr)
        {
            return;
        }
        delete m_Singleton;
        m_Singleton = nullptr;
    }
};

Singleton* Singleton::m_Singleton = nullptr;
```

I want to know the difference between this.
Aren't you creating an object using only one?
Or I wonder if there's any difference.

Comment: you can create more than one instance of `A` but there can be only one `Singleton`

Comment: With a singleton there is only ever one `Foo`.  With your first exmaple there can be `N` `Foo`s

Comment: In what case can you make two? No matter how hard I think about it, I don't know.

Comment: `A a,b;` is two instances of type `A`

Comment: Note that `static A* a;` does not actually declare a variable of type `A`, just an (uninitialized) pointer to one.

Comment: `static` in namespace scope means something else then `static` in class/struct/function scope! `static` in namespace scope means this symbol is visible only in current translation unit. So when you put `static A* a;` in header you will have multiple instances of `a` one for each translation unit including that header. [see dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6034654/1387438).

Comment: An important difference is, beside instance count, the static destruction order. This might affect whether your program crashes or not during exit.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the user (the programmer that use your class) can create as many instances of `A` as he/she wants. The porpouse of the singleton design pattern is to be sure to have just one instance of singleton class (`Singleton` in your case) in the whole program.
This is possible declaring the constructor private and then delegate to a static function the duty to return an instance of the class.

Answer (score -3):

If you refere to a sinlgleton in combination with static you potentially want a setup the static version because it is thread save since C++ 11.

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
};

A* getInstanceOfA() 
{
    static A a; // Thread save magic static implementing singleton
    return &a;
}

A* globalSingleton = nullptr;

A* getInstanceOfAWithNew() 
{
    if(nullptr == globalSingleton) {
        globalSingleton = new A(); // Not thread save. Would need mutex.
    }
    return globalSingleton;
}
```

The C++ 11 standard guarantees these kind of static variables to be thread safe.
The compiler will make sure the static variable `a` is initialized only once.
This isn't given if you use `new A`. You need to use some guard.

See [How to implement multithread safe singleton in C++11 without using](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711920/how-to-implement-multithread-safe-singleton-in-c11-without-using-mutex)

Comment: "This isn't given if you use new A" why not? I might be misreading, but I think you are wrong