# C++ static variable and function errors

Tags: c++, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does it mean to have an undefined reference to a static member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092765/what-does-it-mean-to-have-an-undefined-reference-to-a-static-member)

I have a static class as follows:

.h file

```
class c1 {
    public:
    static int disconnect();
    private:
    static bool isConnected;
    };
```

.cpp file

```
#include c1.h

int c1::disconnect()
{
    c1::isConnected = false;
    return 0;
}
```

However when I compile, there is an error

```
undefined reference to `c1::m_isConnected'
```

Please help!

Comment: So is it c1::m_isConnected or c1::isConnected ?

Comment: @c-smile that is probably caused by name mangling if this is an linker error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide an actual object instance for the static class members. Add the following to your .cpp file:

```
 bool c1::isConnected;
```

To initialize it to a specific value, add an initializer:

```
 bool c1::isConnected = false;
```

(By the way, classes in C++ cannot be static. Classes are just types. Only class *members* can be static.)

Comment: Isn't the "m_" caused by name mangling?

Comment: sweet thx...im coming form C#/C so yeah..

Comment: Not sure about C#, but Java has static classes... in C++, any class that's defined inside another class is called a "nested class". But there's no analogue of a "static (nesterd) class" in C++, i.e. a class that only static member functions can use -- the concept doesn't make sense in C++, where classes are just types.

Answer (score 1):

`isConnected` is a (non-static) member variable and you can't use it without an instance that it's a part of. While static variables exist independently of any object, non-static member variables *only* exist as part of an instance of that class.

You need to either make `isConnected` static or accept an instance of `c1` on which to set `isConnected` to `false`. You probably want the former.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in header file is declaration. However, you also need a definition of the variable. The correct code will look like this:

```
class c1 {
public:
    static int disconnect();
private:
    static bool isConnected;
};

bool c1::isConnected = false;

int c1::disconnect()
{
    isConnected = false;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's important to get the separation of header file and source file right, though, otherwise you might end up with multiple definitions.