# C++ static class member - syntax error

Tags: c++, class, static, syntax-error

I have this code:(`BITMAPS` is a free name)

```
class BITMAPS{
public:
    static ALLEGRO_BITMAP *cursor;

    static void load_bitmaps();
    static void unload_bitmaps();
};
```

and I'm trying to use it like this:(**the lines with the errors**)

```
line 9:   BITMAPS.load_bitmaps();
line 23:  BITMAPS.unload_bitmaps();
line 36:  BITMAPS.cursor;
```

but I'm getting errors like this:(**the errors**)

```
line 9 and 23:    syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
line 36:          token '.' is illegal after UDT 'BITMAPS'
line 36:          'BITMAPS' : illegal use of this type as an expression
line 36:          left of '.cursor' must have class/struct/union
```

what is the problem?

EDIT:

I've changed **.** to **::** and now I'm getting this:

```
unresolved external symbol "public: static struct ALLEGRO_BITMAP * BITMAPS::cursor" (?cursor@BITMAPS@@2PAUALLEGRO_BITMAP@@A)
```

what is this mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use the **Scope Resolution**`::` operator to refer to them, and not the syntax you are using.

```
BITMAPS::load_bitmaps();
BITMAPS::unload_bitmaps();
BITMAPS::cursor;
```

EDIT:  To answer your updated Q

You just **declared** the static member `cursor`, You also need to **define** it,in your source(`cpp`) file.
like:

```
ALLEGRO_BITMAP* BITMAPS::cursor = 0;
```

**Good Read:**
**[what does it mean to have an undefined reference to a static-member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092765/what-does-it-mean-to-have-an-undefined-reference-to-a-static-member)**

**Suggestion:**
You should read a **[good C++ book.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)**

Comment: changed. but now I'm getting another problem. what now?