# why error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol in this case?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Defining static members in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536372/defining-static-members-in-c)
>   [Static method with a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249314/static-method-with-a-field)

I found the below code on singleton implementation on the web, and decide to give it a try:

```
#include <iostream>

class Singleton
{
    Singleton(){}
    static Singleton *s_instance;

public:
    static Singleton* getInstance()
    {
        if(!s_instance)
            s_instance = new Singleton();

        return s_instance;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Singleton::getInstance();
    return(0);
}
```

It looks quite straight forward. But when I build it in Visual Studio, it gives a linker error message:

```
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: static class Singleton
* Singleton::s_instance" (?s_instance@Singleton@@0PAV1@A)
C:\Users\boll\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hello_world\Debug\hello_world.exe :
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals'
```

Why is '`s_instance`' unresolved in this case?

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: You need to define `s_instance` outside the class.

Comment: got it. Thanks chris and Mysticial.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining static members in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536372/defining-static-members-in-c) also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612206/linker-error-when-using-static-members, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585069/weird-linker-error-with-static-stdmap , and more

Comment: actually a little question here: static data member need to be defined once outside of class, that's c++ rule. but why? static member function 'getInstance()' has visibility if we use scope ::, but why 's_instance' cause the unresolved external symbol error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should initialize `s_instance=NULL` before. You can see the following link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1921/Singleton-Pattern-its-implementation-with-C

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you say 'initialize `s_instance = NULL` before', can you elaborate what you mean?  'Before' what?