# How to instantiate a variable from a class with a variable from another class with C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to instantiate a variable `Tt1` from a class called `ÌnletConditions` with the variable `Tt0` from another class with the object `ein_in`.

```
double InletConditions::Tt1 = ein_in.Tt0;
```

The variable `Tt1` is declared as `public static double` in the headerfile of the class `InletConditions`.

```
class InletConditions {
public:
    static double Tt1;
}
```

The variable `Tt0` is declared and instantiated like this:

```
\\ file Eingabe_Konstanten.h
class Eingabe_Konstanten {
public:
    static double Tt0;
}

\\ file Eingabe_Konstanten.cpp
double Eingabe_Konstanten::Tt0 = io_ein.read(1);
```

io_ein.read(int) refers to a method, which reads in a value from the specified line number (int) from a file. The value should become 293.15.

How can I achieve that the value of `Tt1` also becomes 293.15? In the output it is just 0.

```
int main() {
    Eingabe_Konstanten ein;
    InletConditions in;
    std::cout << ein.Tt0 << endl;
    std::cout << in.Tt1 << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
293.15
0
```

I would be pleased if anyone could help me, since I am new to programming and don't know what topic this problem is related to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming `InletConditions` class has a separate file, wouldn't including `Eingabe_Konstanten.h`before `InletConditions.h` solve it?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Try move the initialization steps to same cpp file, this will allow you to set the initialization order explicitly. "Eingabe_Konstanten::Tt0 =" and then "double InletConditions::Tt1 ="

Answer (score 2):

Static variables refer to the class itself and not to a particular object of that class. As such you must call them using the scope resolution operator of the class:

```
InletConditions::Tt1 = Eingabe::Tt0;
std::cout << Eingabe::Tt0 << endl;
std::cout << InletConditions::Tt1 << endl;
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28f3b81e7baeb06d)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that doesn't help, too. I still get `Tt1 = 0` at the output.

Comment: @ClemensFörster if you assign the variables in `main` you get the desired effect, look at the demo.

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong. When I assign it in InletConditions.cpp, it doesn't work.

Comment: I guess I've been hiding something important, see the definition of Tt0 in my question, which I've recently edited. Does it change anything in your answer? Thanks in advance and sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use:

```
int main() {
    Eingabe_Konstanten ein;
    InletConditions in;
    in.Tt1 = ein.Tt0; //You need to assign the value of ein.Tt0 to in.Tt1 here
    std::cout << ein.Tt0 << endl;
    std::cout << in.Tt1 << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! That was just a minimal example of the program. And since I don't want to get the main()-function to big and other classes need the value of Tt1 aswell, this might not be the best solution of the problem. Otherwise this would help.

Comment: You could just create a new function that does the assignment, and use the scope resolution operator as in the answer by @101010 below. See here for an explanation of static variables in C++ - you do not need to create a class instance to use them. http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/811-static-member-variables/

Comment: This one might also help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161697/accessing-a-static-member-function-from-another-class?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will take at look at it.