# Undefined reference std::pair

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, std-pair

One would think that this simple piece of code should compile easily:

```
#include <utility>

struct Q {
    static const int X = 0;
};

int main() {
    std::pair<int, int>(Q::X, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile this with `g++` using the default settings (cygwin gcc 4.5.3) it throws a linker error at me:

```
undefined reference to `Q::X'
```

I'm totally stumped here -- MSVC compiles this just fine yet my gcc does not.  (MinGW also works fine.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linker fails to find definition of `Q::X`.

This is probably because `std::pair<>` constructor takes arguments as references to const, and `Q::X` is an l-value, hence it requires an external definition of `Q::X` to be able to refer to that.

A portable fix:

```
int const Q::X;
```

Comment: Well that's unfortunate; I have like a dozen of these `static const` definitions inside a traits(-like) class so it would be quite a burden to duplicate them outside.  I think I'll just cast it to a value instead so it doesn't try to take a reference.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You only declare X but you must also define it, which, for static definitions must happen outside the class

```
struct Q {
static const int X = 0;
};
int Q::X = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

@Maxim Yegorushkin  (Beat me to it!) [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7092830/2041091) is a relevant link that might help.

But your problem is that the int is never externally defined.  If X doesn't have to be const, you can initialize it outside the struct in a similar manner. The main reason is because X is static...

```
struct Q {
   static const int X;
};
int const Q::X = 0;

struct Q {
   static int X;
};
int Q::X = 0;
```