# c++11 static functional member variable

Tags: c++, c++11, static

Well, I'm stumped. I've always had a bit of a hard time with static member variables and functions, so if the answer to this is really obvious, I apologize. I can't figure out what's wrong, though.

In WSGrid.h:

```
#include <functional>

class WSGrid
{
public:
    //constructors...

    static const std::function< char( void ) > _randomChar;

    //private data...
};
```

In WSGrid.cpp:

```
#include <random>

std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution< char > distribution;

const WSGrid::_randomChar = std::bind( distribution, generator );
```

In my main.cpp:

```
#include "WSGrid.h"
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::cout << WSGrid::_randomChar() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And when I try to compile (`g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp`), I get "undefined reference to WSGrid::_randomChar".

So... it looks, to me, like I'm doing everything right. I'm following the syntax found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092765/what-does-it-mean-to-have-an-undefined-reference-to-a-static-member), at least as far as I'm aware. But apparently there's something wrong.

Comment: `uniform_int_distribution` can not be used with `char`, see ISO [rand.req.genl]

Comment: How strange, then, that it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define `_randomChar` correctly.

update :

```
const WSGrid::_randomChar = std::bind( distribution, generator );
```

to:

```
const std::function<char(void)> WSGrid::_randomChar = std::bind(distribution, generator);
```

Also you need to link `WSGrid.cpp`

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -c WSGrid.cpp -o WSGrid.o
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic main.cpp WSGrid.o
```

Comment: Well. I thought it might have been stupid. Thanks a ton. I'll mark your answer as correct when the time limit expires.