# "Undefined" reference to class member in C++

Tags: c++, oop, gcc, linker

While linking this code:

```
#include <map>
using std::map;
#include <string>
using std::string;
class C {
public:
    static void dump() {
        for (const auto& e : data) {
            string(e.first);
        }
    }
private:
    static map<string,map<string,string>> data;
};
int main() {
    C::dump();
}
```

... I get this error:

```
/tmp/cc4W2iNa.o: In function `C::dump()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN1C4dumpEv[_ZN1C4dumpEv]+0x9): undefined reference to `C::data'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

... from g++ (GCC) 4.9.1.
Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: We really should find a less confusing duplicate for this question (or bang it into a more generic shape), but it's still the highest voted one to be found on topic.

Comment: A more comprehensive duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092765

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've declared `C::data`, but not defined it. Add a definition outside the class:

```
map<string,map<string,string>> C::data;
```

In a larger program, which more than one source file, this must go in just one source file to satisfy the One Definition Rule; while the class definition (including the declaration of `data`) might go in a header to be available wherever it's needed.

Comment: Some notes from your side about closing as a dupe, and finding a more appropriate one?

Comment: I have to define a non-function class member? Srsly?!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: This one, perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092765

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrowitschKlim: Yes, seriously. That's what the One Definition Rule requires.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Yeah, it's much more abstract/generic but lacks votes :P ...