# Overriding function from caller source file in C++

Tags: c++

There is a c++ file called main.cpp.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "addition.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(){
   int x=2;
   int y=3;
   std::cout<<getsum(x,y);
}
```

This file includes custom header file called **addition.h**

**addition.h**

```
#include "my_adders.h"
namespace{
int getsum(int a,int b){
    return calculate_addition_h(a,b);
}
}
```

**my_adders.h**

```
#include <maths.h>
int calculate_addition_h(int p, int q){

      int sum=0;
      //Fn definitions
      return sum;
}
```

In main.cpp, 
i need to override the definition of calculate_addition_h function.

Is it possible?

I tried copying calculate_addition_h definition as well as declaration in main.cpp. However, when, i printed the o/p, calculate_addition_h method in my_adders.h was invoked, not the one in main.cpp.

Please note: I cannot make any changes to addition.h or my_adders.h.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: @Andreas Grapentin: edited. Thanks

Comment: I guess you could put your own version in a separate namespace (e.g. `namespace overridden_adders`) and then force that one to be used through a `using` statement.

Comment: I thought the namespace keyword took an argument?

Comment: Wht do you mean by saying "override definition"? Do you want to overload this function, i.e. to provide a function with different parameters? Or do you want do define another function with exactly the same signature?

Comment: @JaredBeekman It's an [unnamed namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422507/superiority-of-unnamed-namespace-over-static).

Comment: @Igor R.: Its not overloading. Parameters and function name remains the same only the  definition of the function needs to be changed.

Comment: Ok, I see - you want another function to be called from within `getsum`. No, it's not possible without really dirty preprocessors tricks. The person who wrote it didn't intend to make it polymorphic.

Comment: @IgorR.: It is possible, check my anwser. The code is still... dodgy, to say the least.

Comment: The obvious question is why do you want to do such thing?

Comment: @gwiazdorrr oh, very good point!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it is possible without altering any of the headers and preprocessor magic!

Since your `getsum` is in an unnamed namespace, you can define `calculate_addition_h` function in the unnamed namespace *before* including addition.h:

**main.cpp**

```
namespace
{
    int calculate_addition_h(int p, int q)
    {
        return 666;
    }
}

#include "addition.h"
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    int x=2;
    int y=3;
    std::cout<<getsum(x,y);
}
```

In C++, functions in same namespace take precedence over functions in parent namespaces. In this case parent namespace is the global one.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using global function, so it is not possible to override the function as it can be done in `class`. Its better to define a new function with the same name inside a different `namespace`