# Is it worth declaring functions as static?

Tags: c++, static-functions

In C or C++ you can declare a function to be `static` if it is only used in a single Translation Unit (i.e. file), for example:

```
static int square(int a) {
    return a * a;
}
```

This should allow the compiler to optimise it better. It's a bit ugly though (*edit: opinions on the ugliness may vary; this question isn't about that*), and I'd rather not have to do it if I don't need to. How much difference does it *really* make?

1. Does it affect compile times?
2. What is the overhead for calling a non-`static` function that could be `static`?
3. Can the linker recognise that it is only used in one file and automatically turn it back into a `static` function (maybe with `-flto` or ThinLTO?).

*Edit: Answers for any achitecture & compiler are welcome, though obviously more common ones are more helpful (Clang, x86-64).*

Comment: Please narrow down the specific compiler(s) you're asking this question for. It's very compiler-dependant. With LTO they'll definitely get optimized out.

Comment: "_It's a bit ugly though_" Why is it ugly? If the function is helper function inside a translation unit, and should not be callable externally, why should it have external linkage?

Comment: A major reason to do this is to prevent name clashes with similar functions in other units, which will cause silent undefined behaviour. There's no reason not to do it really.

Comment: `static` is about as ugly as `private`. No matter your taste, hiding names is useful without even considering optimization.

Comment: I always do this religiously, duplicate symbol definitions in large projects are not much fun.  Especially important when you use a name like that.  C++ has namespace support so it is a lot less critical.

Comment: It affects linking times more than compile times.

Comment: Note - in C++ you better use anonymous namespace.

Comment: @Slava: They are effectively the same for functions. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4422554/265521).

Comment: @Timmmm They are not the same for everything else, that already good enough reason to use anonymous namespace for everything, rather than differentiate it.