# Why does google test sample put tests in an anonymous namespace?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

This is NOT a duplicate of [Superiority of unnamed namespace over static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422507/superiority-of-unnamed-namespace-over-static)
Please read the question carefully before marking it as duplicate.  I am *not* asking why use an unnamed namespace versus static!
I am asking, why are *google tests* placed inside an unnamed namespace?  Is this some convention that *google tests* follow, and if so, why?  The tests work fine whether they are in an unnamed namespace or not, so obviously it is not required.**

I cloned google test from github and built it for my mac.  It works fine, but I noticed in the sample test code they give they place the tests in an unnamed namespace.  Does anyone know why?

For example, see following file: 
googletest/googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc 
(https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/samples/sample1_unittest.cc#L41)

Part of the file looks like this:

```
// Step 1. Include necessary header files such that the stuff your
// test logic needs is declared.
//
// Don't forget gtest.h, which declares the testing framework.

#include <limits.h>
#include "sample1.h"
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
namespace {

// Step 2. Use the TEST macro to define your tests.
...
TEST(FactorialTest, Negative) {
// This test is named "Negative", and belongs to the "FactorialTest"
// test case.
EXPECT_EQ(1, Factorial(-5));
EXPECT_EQ(1, Factorial(-1));
EXPECT_GT(Factorial(-10), 0);
}
...
}  // namespace
```

Does anyone know why all the tests are in an unnamed namespace?
I tried removing the unnamed namespace and the sample still worked fine, so clearly it is not necessary for this particular sample.

Comment: Please read the question more carefully before marking it as a duplicate!

Comment: Class definition can't be static, right? Why would you want to risk your test code clashing with your application code at link time?

Comment: An example of good coding practice might not actually be necessary in
a particular application of the example. It is good practice not to give external linkage to symbols gratuitously. You don't need to ask a programmer why *haven't* put stuff into the global namespace.
You need to ask why they *have*.

Comment: @Mike, good point.  I especially like the phrase "You don't need to ask a programmer why haven't put stuff into the global namespace. You need to ask why they have."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the comment by [Mike Kinghan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1362568/mike-kinghan) answers the question, especially the part

> You don't need to ask a programmer why haven't put stuff into the global namespace. You need to ask why they have.

However, I think its a good idea, pedagogically, to give an example of the kind of horrors that can happen if one doesn't follow good coding practices and as a consequence, violate [ODR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) by mistake.

First, to relate the program below with the question, one needs to know that some of the Google Test macros create new classes. Now, consider the following program

**myClass1.h**

```
#ifndef MYCLASS1_H
#define MYCLASS1_H

int f();    

#endif  /* MYCLASS1_H */
```

**myClass2.h**

```
#ifndef MYCLASS2_H
#define MYCLASS2_H

int g();    

#endif  /* MYCLASS2_H */
```

**myClass1.cpp**

```
#include "myClass1.h"

class MyClass {
public:
    void twice() { val *= 2; }
    char val;
};    

int f() {
    MyClass x;
    x.val = 2;
    x.twice();
    return x.val;
}
```

**myClass2.cpp**

```
#include "myClass2.h"

class MyClass {
public:
    void twice() { val *= 2; }
    double val;
};    

int g() {
    MyClass x;
    x.val = 3;
    x.twice();
    return x.val;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myClass1.h"
#include "myClass2.h"

int main() {
    std::cerr << f() << std::endl << g() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Notice how the class `MyClass` has two different definitions. With g++ 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10, compiling and running the program with

```
g++ -O3 myClass1.cpp myClass2.cpp main.cpp -o undefined && ./undefined
```

prints **4** and **6**, the expected behavior. However, compiling and running with no optimizations, i.e. with

```
g++ -O0 myClass1.cpp myClass2.cpp main.cpp -o undefined && ./undefined
```

prints **4** and **3**!

Now, put this bug in a non-trivial program and you might easily loose an afternoon of debugging, especially if the bug laid dormant for a while. On the other hand, wrapping the classes in anonymous namespaces up-front takes no time at all and it prevents the bug. I think this illustrates one of the rationale behind some of the good coding practices: basic risk management.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little? Is it that a cast from `3` prefer to choose `char` as a target before finding the `float` alternative, but `x.twice()` gets linked to latter anyway?