# What does it mean when the function in global namespace is declared as static C++?

Tags: c++, function, static, return-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a “static” function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558122/what-is-a-static-function)

I have seen a function in a global namespace that is declared like this:

```
static int function_name(int a, double* p, int c, float * u)
{
     //do something with these arguments
}
```

What the static keyword means here?

EDIT: Now when I know what is for static, please explain what advantage gives the restriction of a function to be visible in a file only where it is declared? I mean why I should restrict my function visibility, what it gives to me?

Comment: It's not the return type which is static, it's rather the function which is declared static!

Comment: Please stop voting for closing this question. Let's get the answer of my edit part as well.

Comment: Fix the title, then. Or let it be closed and ask a new question about the benefits of file-static.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use a static function with the scope in the compilation unit when you really want the function with that name to be known only inside that compilation unit.  A class or function that is not in that scope cannot accidentally call the function.   (I'd have put this in a comment but I don't have privileges for that yet)

Comment: One example I can think of is if you need to pass a callback function to some other API.

Comment: It's hard to come up with a specific example, because ideally, in C++, if you really wanted a utility function that was only seen in a certain scope, you'd put it in a class.  I can see why you are wondering "why would I use this".  I think it is more that it can be done, and it is because C++ is based on C, vs. some purity of the language and the ability to do this having some great meaning.  Java changed that and said "put your functions in a class" so you can't do this.  But in C++ it is there because of C.

Answer (score 6):

The return value is not static int. The function is a static function returning an int.

See [what is a static funciton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558122/what-is-a-static-function)

Comment: But it is not a class member function, then what is it for the "static"?

Comment: In that case it means that the function has internal linkage, which means that it cannot be referred to from other translational units. Both uses are mentioned in the link that I gave.

Comment: What @DasBoot said is correct, but I'd like to explain a bit. "Translational unit" normally means: the same file. So if a function is declared static you can only call it within the same *.c file, not from other *.c files. The point is to avoid name collisions and also to make the function "private".

Answer (score 3):

It isn't the return value that's static, it's the function. It means that the function is visible within that compilation unit (= file, approximately) but not elsewhere.

Comment: to be completely correct, a compilation unit != file, though that is most often the scope and is, in fact, the smallest scope.  A case where a compilation unit is more than a file is when one file #include's another file.

Comment: It's because "compilation unit" isn't strictly the same as "file" that I said "compilation unit" rather than just "file". It's because most of the time you can treat them as the same that I said "(= file)" rather than just "compilation unit". But yes, I should be a little more explicit about the fact that the two aren't quite equivalent; I'll add a note to my answer. (Apologies for the fact that it will make nonsense of your comment to anyone who doesn't bother reading this!)

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, static refers to the whole function, not its return type. I want to add that the use of the static keyword in this context is ***deprecated*** in C++. [Anonymous namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions) are the better way to go.

```
namespace 
{
   int function_name(int a, double* p, int c, float * u)
}
```

Comment: This specific deprecation has been un-deprecated in C++0x, by the way.

Comment: It is actually un-deprecated again in C++0x, so it is not obviously too bad to use it. :-)

Comment: But why to use it? What it gives me?

Comment: @Narek: This is a way to specify that your function has internal linkage, that is, it cannot be seen or called from other translation units (cpp files).

Comment: @Narek: One advantage is less namespace pollution, and thus less risk of name clashes.

Comment: No, for that case I have a better solution with namespaces, indeed. So I will never use static for that reason. Another reason is necessary for its use!

Comment: @Narek: Are you asking about a useful application of `static` in C++, or are you wondering why it exists? Hint: C does not have namespaces.