# Rationale of un-deprecating static keyword for nonmember functions

Tags: c++, static, c++11

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deprecation of the static keyword… no more ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726570/deprecation-of-the-static-keyword-no-more)

I am asking this question because of a comment [on an answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300627/what-does-it-mean-when-the-function-return-value-is-static-int-in-c/5300680#5300680) which states that the use of static keyword on freestanding (nonmember) functions has been un-deprecated in C++0x.

Since I have no reason to doubt the above statement, I am asking this:

Can anybody please shed light on the underlying rationale of un-deprecating the use of static keyword in that context? (I mean, in C++03 the standard states that anonymous namespaces provide a superior alternative. What's changed?)

Thanks in advance

Comment: It was never deprecated. Look closely at the quote in the "possible duplicate" question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4726570/: "The use of the static keyword is deprecated *when declaring objects in namespace scope*". A function is not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this in the CWG issues list:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#174