# static function in C

Tags: c, static

What is the point of making a function static in C?

Comment: @nightcracker: There are no such things as "methods" in C++. I think you're confused with Objective-C.

Comment: Nah, I'm confused with Python. A function inside a class is called a method in Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a "static" function? (in C)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558122/what-is-a-static-function-in-c)

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Making a function `static` hides it from other translation units, which helps provide [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

**helper_file.c**

```
int f1(int);        /* prototype */
static int f2(int); /* prototype */

int f1(int foo) {
    return f2(foo); /* ok, f2 is in the same translation unit */
                    /* (basically same .c file) as f1         */
}

int f2(int foo) {
    return 42 + foo;
}
```

**main.c**:

```
int f1(int); /* prototype */
int f2(int); /* prototype */

int main(void) {
    f1(10); /* ok, f1 is visible to the linker */
    f2(12); /* nope, f2 is not visible to the linker */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is translation unit the correct terminology to use here? Wouldn't object file be more accurate? From what I understand, a static function is hidden from the linker and the linker does not operate on translation units.

Comment: I should have also said, that I like to think of it as being hidden from the linker; it seems clearer that way.

Comment: so, internal function (that we sure not to call it outside of its c file), we should put it as static function, right ? So, we can sure it cannot call elsewhere. Thanks :)

Comment: How do you compile this? Do you use `#include <helper_file.c>`? I think that would make it a single translation unit then...

Comment: @Atcold: the way I wrote the code you simply include the 2 source files in the command line, like this `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra main.c helper_file.c`. The prototypes for the functions are present in both source files (no need for header files). The linker will resolve the functions.

Comment: When the goal is to make a function "private" to the current file, another way of doing this is to not put the prototype in the header file and to only include the header file (not the .c file) in other files. That is, only declare the function in a separate compilation unit. When this is done, it seems like there's no need to declare the function `static`. The latter practice actually seems more common in the wild. Please explain if I'm wrong, I'm a little foggy on this, even though it's basic.

Comment: @mheiber: when you don't declare a function `static` the linker can find it even without a prototype. The absence of the prototype prevents the compiler from checking return and parameter types, not from issuing code that calls the function.

Comment: @pmg thanks for explaining. I couldn't actual test the behavior you describe, since my code wouldn't compile when I tried to call something that wasn't in the header file. Also, when I look at C projects on GitHub, I'm just not seeing "private" functions (functions one wouldn't want called outside the current file) declared static—are these developers doing things incorrectly? (sorry for all the noob questions!)

Comment: How does it help provide encapsulation? Didn't you mean data hiding?

Comment: @handris static implies internal linkage, hence its inaccessible in other `.c` files(translation units)

Comment: Your answer is correct but the file organisation is inappropriate. You should create a header `helper_file.h`, **declare** functions in the `helper_file.h` and define them in `helper_file.c`. Then the `main.c` file should **include** the `helper_file.h`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 86):

**pmg** is spot on about encapsulation; beyond hiding the function from other translation units (or rather, *because* of it), making functions `static` can also confer performance benefits in the presence of compiler optimizations.

Because a `static` function cannot be called from anywhere outside of the current translation unit (unless the code takes a pointer to its address), the compiler controls all the call points into it.

This means that it is free to use a non-standard ABI, inline it entirely, or perform any number of other optimizations that might not be possible for a function with external linkage.

Comment: ...unless the function's address is taken.

Comment: @caf What do you mean by function's address is taken? To me, the notion of functions/variable having addresses or being assigned address at compile time is a little confusing. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @crypticcoder: Your program is loaded in memory, therefore functions also have a memory location and the address can be obtained. With a function pointer, you could call any of those. If you do that, it reduces the list of optimizations the compiler can perform since the code must stay intact at the same place.

Comment: @crypticcoder: I mean that an expression evaluates a pointer to the function and does something with it other than immediately call the function.  If a pointer to a `static` function escapes the current translation unit, then that function could be directly called from other translation units.

Comment: @caf if the function's address is taken, would the compiler detect that and turn off the static function optimizations mentioned in this answer (eg using a non-standard ABI)? I suppose it'd have to.

Comment: @sevko: Yes - it's not too hard though, because being static at least any expression that takes the function's address has to be in the same source file.

Answer (score 33):

The `static` keyword in C is used in a compiled file (.c as opposed to .h) so that the function exists only in that file.

Normally, when you create a function, the compiler generates cruft the linker can use to, well, link a function call to that function. If you use the static keyword, other functions within the same file can call this function (because it can be done without resorting to the linker), while the linker has no information letting other files access the function.

Comment: 3Doub: Use of the word "cruft" is more precise than you give it credit for.   In the context of the question, "cruft" is the right word to use here.

Comment: @3Doubloons I agree that it's simplified, but I think that makes it that much easier to understand for beginners.

Answer (score 14):

Looking at the posts above I would like to give a more clarified answer:

Suppose our `main.c` file looks like this:

```
#include "header.h"

int main(void) {
    FunctionInHeader();
}
```

Now consider three cases:

- Case 1:
  Our `header.h` file looks like this:

  ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   static void FunctionInHeader();

   void FunctionInHeader() {
       printf("Calling function inside header\n");
   }
  ```

  Then the following command on linux:

  ```
   gcc main.c -o main
  ```

  **will succeed**! That's because after the `main.c` file includes the `header.h`, the static function definition will be in the same `main.c` file (more precisely, in the same translation unit) to where it's called.

  If one runs `./main`, the output will be `Calling function inside header`, which is what that static function should print.
- Case 2: Our header `header.h` looks like this:

  ```
    static void FunctionInHeader();
  ```

  and we also have one more file `header.c`, which looks like this:

  ```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "header.h"

    void FunctionInHeader() {
        printf("Calling function inside header\n");
    }
  ```

  Then the following command

  ```
    gcc main.c header.c -o main
  ```

  will give an error. In this case `main.c` includes only the declaration of the static function, but the definition is left in another translation unit and the `static` keyword prevents the code defining a function to be linked
- Case 3:

  Similar to case 2, except that now our header `header.h` file is:

  ```
    void FunctionInHeader(); // keyword static removed
  ```

  Then the same command as in case 2 will succeed, and further executing `./main` will give the expected result. Here the `FunctionInHeader` definition is in another translation unit, but the code defining it can be linked.

Thus, to conclude:

```
static keyword prevents the code defining a function to be linked,
when that function is defined in another translation unit than where it is called.
```

Answer (score 5):

C programmers use the static attribute to hide variable and function declarations inside modules,
much as you would use public and private declarations in Java and C++. C source files play the role of
modules. Any global variable or function declared with the static attribute is private to that module.
Similarly, any global variable or function declared without the static attribute is public and can be
accessed by any other module. It is good programming practice to protect your variables and functions
with the static attribute wherever possible.

Answer (score 5):

pmg's answer is very convincing. If you would like to know how static declarations work at object level then this below info could be interesting to you.
I reused the same program written by pmg and compiler it into a .so(shared object) file

Following contents are after dumping the .so file into something **human readable**

0000000000000675 **f1**: *address of f1 function*

000000000000068c **f2**: *address of f2(staticc) function*

note the difference in the function address , it means something . For a function that's declared with different address , it can very well signify that f2 lives very far away or in a different segment of the object file.

Linkers use something called PLT(Procedure linkage table) and GOT(Global offsets table) to understand symbols that they have access to link to .

For now think that GOT and PLT magically bind all the addresses and a dynamic section holds information of all these functions that are visible by linker.

After dumping the dynamic section of the .so file we get a bunch of entries but only interested in **f1** and **f2** function.

The dynamic section holds entry only for **f1** function at address **0000000000000675** and not for **f2** !

Num:    Value          Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name

```
 9: 0000000000000675    23 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 f1
```

And thats it !. From this its clear that the linker will be unsuccessful in finding the **f2** function since its not in the dynamic section of the .so file.

Answer (score 0):

When there is a need to restrict access to some functions, we'll use the static keyword while defining and declaring a function.

```
            /* file ab.c */ 
static void function1(void) 
{ 
  puts("function1 called"); 
} 
And store the following code in another file ab1.c

/* file ab1.c  */ 
int main(void) 
{ 
 function1();  
  getchar(); 
  return 0;   
} 
/* in this code, we'll get a "Undefined reference to function1".Because function 1 is declared static in file ab.c and can't be used in ab1.c */
```

Comment: This answer is not very helpful.