# if I define a function in the implementation (.cpp) file without defining it in the header file what happens?

Tags: c++, function

I'm a C++ noob. I have a foo.cpp file which defines a function,

```
void sort() {
   // details of sort algorithm
}
```

I have not defined this in the corresponding header file, but I get no compilation error. I noticed this is taken as a static method. Is that the case? What exactly have I done here?

EDIT:

I've noticed that inside this method I can't use this, (ex: this->bar), hence my assumption that this is a static function. This actually happened when I wanted a 'private' method, but forgot to declare it in the header file. Is there an actual use of such a function?

Comment: `what happens?` Try it and enlighten us as well

Comment: You've defined a free-standing function that's still callable from other .cpp files (it's not a static function), but the caller will get less help getting it right and will have to prototype the function themselves (since your question is a about C++ - in C they could get away with just calling the function, hoping they passed the correct argument types, and possibly not finding out if they were wrong until some bug was noticed).

Comment: In your title, you mean "... *declaring* (not defining) it in the header file."

Comment: @MichaelBurr Implicit function declarations haven't been in C since 1999, I believe.

Comment: The reason you cannot access `this` is different from everything else that happens. You can't use `this` because it isn't part of any class. Unlike Java, C++ doesn't automatically associate everything in one file with one class; that's just common practice. Since it isn't part of a class, you can't use `this` any more than you can in any other free function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not invisible outside of that compilation unit, it is not bound to a single compilation unit, it is just a definition that needs a declaration in order to be called. Like any other definition.

wtf.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
void f(){ std::cout<< "f();"; }
```

omg.cpp:

```
void f(); // I can declare wherever I use it.
int main(){ f(); }
```

`$ g++ wtf.cpp omg.cpp && ./a.out`

Output: `f();`

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not taken as a static function. It is just not visible to the other transllation unnits, and so you cannot use it.

The difference in regard to a static method is, that the linker sees the function. So if you define a function with the same name in another translation unit, you will probably either get a linker error (best case) or the wrong method called at times.

PS: I talk about a *functions* rather than *methods* here, because in C++ a method typically is part of a class, and you cannot define a method for a class if that method isn't declared in that class' declaration.

Comment: This statement/answer might not be factually accurate. This function can still be used in the same unit

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ: Yes, that's why I said it's not visible to the *other* translation units. You are even able to use that function in other units, if you add a declaration to those translation units (which would be bad style).

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happens. The function will be there and essentially available, but without a prototype/forward declaration other translation units/parts of the code won't know it's actually there (and based on optimization level it might be excluded from the resulting executable code).

Answer (score 3):

the function is like the others said available in that translation unit.
But you can still access it from anywhere as it will just have external linkage. so just do this:

```
void foo()
{
    extern void sort();

    sort();
}
```

Comment: Are u assuming this is C as opposed to C++?

Answer (score 2):

You've created a function that is only visible to that compilation unit (and others that include the source itself).

Answer (score 1):

You've just have defined a free function .

You can use in your implementation file given that the declaration is **above** the calls (the parser "reads" the source file from top to bottom) :

```
void fun(){
   mysort(); // Compile Error

void mysort(){}

void anotherFun(){
   mysort(); // Works here
   }
```

To get rid of this boundary effect, you can add a prototype of the function at the beginning of the file. I often use this "free function" for small conversion macros.

> Example :

```
char* BigEndianToLitteEndian( char word[], int size); // prototype

void routine()
{
  ....
  le = BigEndianToLittleEndian( be, SIZE );
  ....

}

char* BigEndianToLitteEndian( char word[], int size){ // implementation
   ....
}
```

Comment: I would avoid using `Crash` as indication of an error. It suggest runtime context, but actually is a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's only in the implementation file, it's not static unless you specify `static`.

Static functions, in addition to restricting access, may also allow for compiler optimizations for better performance.

See [static function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319361/static-function-in-c), notably [@Stephen_Canon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5319418/242933).

Answer (score 1):

And also it might be very bad if the same function defined inside some other cpp file with the same signature.

Comment: That's not going to be bad, the linker is going to catch that and throw an error. Only if the functions are specifically declared as `inline`, `static` or if it's templated (in which case it becomes `inline`) they can exist in more than one compilation unit.

Comment: Was not able to try it actually. So that's nice to hear :).