# Does unused static functions in headers, increase the kernel module size?

Tags: c, size, kernel-module, static-functions

Static functions are functions that are only visible to other functions in the same file (below link).

[static function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319361/static-function-in-c)

While developing a loadable kernel module, I should include many headers. These headers implement too many static functions that I dont use them.

For example see the below link (skbuff.h) for implemented static functions:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/skbuff.h

Does unused static functions in headers, increase the kernel module size?

Comment: Shouldn't the inline keyword in your sample make all those functions only placed in code when they are used?

Comment: @LostBoy that's up to the compiler