# Unknown symbol when compiling kernel module from multiple files

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am writing a kernel module that is comprised of several source files,
One of these source files has a function that needs to be used by the other objects in the same module.

It is defined in my file named ModemAPI.c

```
static void LogMessage ( char *format, ...)
```

This c file should be (together with other files) compiled into one kernel module, its makefile looks like this:

```
obj-m += ModemAPI.o

ModemAPI-objs := ../Common/StateMachine.o ../Common/ElementsPool.o
```

When I compile this kernel module, I get a warning during linking that the above function "LogMessage" is undefined and when I try to load the module I get an error saying it has an unknown symbol in it (of course LogMessage).

EDIT: Just to make clear, the function "LogMessage" is declared and implemented in the file ModemAPI.c, moreover it is exported via EXPORT_SYMBOL

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL(LogMessage);
```

In the files that use the function (such as StateMachine.c), it is declared via extern

```
extern void LogMessage ( char *format, ...);
```

The module compiles, the problem is in the linking stage.

Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem with this?

Thanks,
Roy.

Comment: I guess, you should look this section once http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration

Comment: Hi, please read the section I have added via edit, the symbols are defined via extern in the file that uses the function.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for : `moreover it is exported via EXPORT_SYMBOL`

`EXPORT_SYMBOL()` makes `LogMessage()` is accessible to loadable kernel modules.

For eample, `vmalloc()` is exported to use in kernel modules http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/vmalloc.c#L1708

But still you have to include the [vmalloc.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/vmalloc.h#L67) in loadable kernel module source.so do not confuse with extern and EXPORT_SYMBOL.

**Solution**

In your Makefile, modify as below

```
obj-m += ModemAPI.c StateMachine.c
```

i.e ModemAPI.c which has LogMessage() should be compiled first.

**Change proposed to Makefile**

```
obj-m += Mymodule.o

Mymodule-objs := ../Common/ModemAPI.o ../Common/StateMachine.o ../Common/ElementsPool.o
```

**EDIT : 2**

static in `static void LogMessage ( char *format, ...)` restricts the use of LogMessage() in other files. This concept is called [static functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319361/static-function-in-c).

Comment: StateMachine.c is not a seperate module, it is a source file that will compile (together with ModemAPI.c) into a single module.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the help. Second, I tried the makefile you have suggested and the problem remains the same.

WARNING: "LogMessage" [Base/Driver/Mymodule.ko] undefined!

Answer (score 0):

In the Makefile try

```
obj-m += Module.o

Module-objs :=  ../Common/StateMachine.o ../Common/ElementsPool.o ../Common/ModemAPI.o
```

some times the order of the .o files are important

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that ModemAPI.c is not getting compiled.

> obj-m += ModemAPI.o 
>   ModemAPI-objs := ../Common/StateMachine.o ../Common/ElementsPool.o

Normally `obj-m += ModemAPI.o` tells `make` to use ModemAPI.c (I think that is the default for the linux make system), but adding the ModemAPI-objs tells `make` that ModemAPI.o is built using the objects `../Common/StateMachine.o ../Common/ElementsPool.o` instead.

Try renaming the object or your ModemAPI.c file:

```
 obj-m += modem.o #something not named ModemAPI.o
 ModemAPI-objs := ModemAPI.o ../Common/StateMachine.o ../Common/ElementsPool.o
```

or

```
 obj-m += ModemAPI.o 
 ModemAPI-objs := main.o ../Common/StateMachine.o ../Common/ElementsPool.o
```

where ModemAPI.c has been renamed to main.c

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure, that your kernel is compiled with support for module loading (e.g., if `/proc/modules` exists, you can be sure, it is)
2. Make sure, you are compiling against the same kernel, where you are trying to load the module
3. define `obj-m` += ... and `[my-module-ko]-objs` := [all xx.o object list]