# Objective C Program

Tags: objective-c, c

Can someone explain the following code to me? I'm confused on the return values and the meaning of "static inline".

```
static inline CGFloat skRandf()
{
    return rand() / (CGFloat) RAND_MAX;
}

static inline CGFloat skRand(CGFloat low, CGfloat high)
{
    return skRandf() * (high - low) + low;
}
```

Comment: Added C tag because this is actually pure C and there is nothing specific to Objective-C.

Answer (score 2):

Both functions return a type of [`CGFloat`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgfloat), which is a platform-dependent type that holds either a 32-bit or 64-bit floating point number.

`static` is a C keyword that ensures the function in question isn't visible to other [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). In many cases, this means that code outside the source file in which the `static` function was defined cannot invoke the function. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319361/static-function-in-c) for more details about exactly how `static` works in C.

`inline` is a C keyword that suggests to (but not requires that) the compiler that the function should be compiled inline; e.g. instead of making a call the body of the function is substituted in at the call site. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function) goes into what `inline` does in more detail.