# MSVS/MSVC Static Template Class Method Does Not Warn

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, static

A while ago, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31305717/member-function-with-static-linkage) was asked, regarding the familiar

```
error: 'static' can only be specified inside the class definition
```

error.

In my current use-case, I am moving from a very MSVC project, where almost all the code is compiled using MSVC, and cross compiling for Android.

> I noticed that there is no MSVC error, least of all, a warning, about static class methods having definitions inside (outside) the class. Am I missing something? Why is there not at least a warning?

---

**EDIT**

To clarify, I am asking why there is no proper MSVC/MSVS warning for code such as this (taken from the link, above):

```
class Foobar {
public:
  static void do_something();
};
static void Foobar::do_something() {} // Error!

int main() {
    Foobar::do_something();
}
```

---

**EDIT**

So sorry evey one! This sample doesn't work! My apologies.

```
class Foobar {
public:
  template<class Y> 
  static int do_something();
};

template<class Y> 
static int Foobar::do_something() {return 1;} // Error!

int main() {
    return Foobar::do_something<double>();
}
```

Here is the output from [MSVC 19.14](https://godbolt.org/z/YTTWB0) (success), and [GCC 4.12](https://godbolt.org/z/uAJpzY) (failure).

Comment: We need an [MCVE] in which you'd expect a warning.

Comment: It's perfectly OK (and normal) to have static function definitions outside the class - but you can't label them as `static` in that context.

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword from the out of line defenitions?  I'm unclear to what you are trying to ask here

Comment: @tkausl One such example is provided in the hyperlink in the post.

Comment: @NeilButterworth see edit. I understand that the solution is to delete the `static` word, prior to the definition. That is why I have included the previous post.

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/HFysEM)

Comment: Note that you will get the error message regardless of whether `do_something` is a template or not. Unless you are using some strange old version of MSVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS 2012 Update 5, VS 2013 Update 5, VS 2015 Update 3 and VS 2017 (15.9 update) all report an error for this code:

```
error C2724: 'Foobar::do_something': 'static' should not be used
             on member functions defined at file scope
```

I'm guessing the code built only with an older, non-conformant version of Visual C++.

Note that if you want to clean up code using the Visual C++ compiler to make it easier to port to other platforms:

- You can use VS 2017 with the `/permissive-` switch. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/).
- There are a number of conformance switches to try as well such as `/Zc:__cplusplus`. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/04/09/msvc-now-correctly-reports-__cplusplus/).

> Using `/permissive-` already implies `/Zc:strictStrings`, `/Zc:rvalueCast`, and `/Zc:ternary` and enables [two-phase name look-up](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/).

- You can also use `/Wall`, although it takes some effort to get all the noise down to see the useful warnings. It's still not as fussy as `clang`, but it's helpful. For an example of a bunch of stuff to suppress, see the top of [this header](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/pch.h).
- There is also an experimental C99 preprocessor you can try, although that one is still in the early stages. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/07/06/msvc-preprocessor-progress-towards-conformance/)

> You can try it out yourself with the VS 2017 Community edition.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Big error on my part. Please, see the edit.

Comment: Thats why I asked half an hour ago a snipped/MCVE of __your__ code, not just _any_ code.

Comment: `/Wall` is completely useless because it is incompatible with standard C++ headers. Compiling with `/W4`, however, is a good idea.

Comment: @ChristianHackl - ``Wall`` turns on a bunch of off-by-default stuff that is useful if you take the time to silence all the stuff that isn't... I use it for my various GitHub projects, although I agree it's a lot of work. See also [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/12/13/broken-warnings-theory/)

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn: I don't know... I get a few pages of warnings if I just include `<iostream>`, without even *using* anything from the header. Perhaps what works best is compiling with `/W4` in your project's standard configuration and inspecting the `/Wall` results only every once in a while to avoid wasting time and resources.

Comment: There's also the opposite approach of turning on [off-by-default warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/compiler-warnings-that-are-off-by-default) that are most useful for you. In any case, Visual C++ does have a lot more warnings it can emit even if it doesn't in most cases. I'm wondering what version if MSVC the OP's code actually built with... VS 2010? VS .NET 2008? I don't have those toolsets on my computer anymore and honestly I should trim VS 2012/VS 2013 :)