# Linking Libraries in C, unidentified reference

Tags: c, gcc

I am trying to link a library to my c program so that my main program can use functions inside the library I am creating, however I am getting errors.

This is some of my library code (well call this file lib.c):

```
#include <bfd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void doDump ( bfd *abfd )
{
    printf (_("\n%s:     file format %s\n"), bfd_get_filename (abfd), abfd->xvec->name);
    doHeaders ( abfd );
}
```

This is my main program (well call this file main.c):

```
#include "bfd.h"

static void getFile ( char *filename, char *target )
{
    bfd *file;
    file = bfd_openr (filename, target);
    doDump (file);
    bfd_close (file);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *target = NULL;
    bfd_init ();
    getFile ("a.out", target);
}
```

These are the commands I run to link the libraries:

> cc -Wall -c lib.c
>
> ar -cvq libdata.a lib.o
>
> cc -o mainprog main.c lib.a -lbfd

However, I am getting this error:

> undefined reference to doDump

Which is pointing to the line:

> doDump (file);

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/558132/477878

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have defined doDump in lib.c as `static`.  This means it is invisible outside that file.  Remove the `static` keyword and the problem should go away.

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that. Thanks

Comment: Also, the linker processes files in the order given, if something is defined but only used later, it won't be included (and thus give an error). Always place libraries last.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have declared `doDump` to be `static` it will not be "visible" in your main program. Remove the `static` qualifier and provide a valid declaration in your `main.c` (or some other header):

```
extern void doDump(bfd * file);

static void getFile ( char *filename, char *target )
{
    bfd *file;
    file = bfd_openr (filename, target);
    doDump (file);
    bfd_close (file);
}
```