# What does "static" mean in the context of declaring global template functions?

Tags: c++, function, templates

I know what *static* means in the context of declaring global non-template functions (see e.g. [What is a "static" function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558122/what-is-a-static-function)), which is useful if you write a helper function in a header that is included from several different locations and want to avoid "duplicate definition" errors.

So my question is: What does *static* mean in the context of declaring global template functions? Please note that I'm specifically asking about *global*, *non-member* template functions that do not belong to a class.

In other words, what is the difference between the following two:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T t)
{
    /* implementation of foo here */
}

template <typename T>
static void bar(T t)
{
    /* implementation of bar here */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a template function is not actually 'compiled' unless an instance of that template function is required.

Then, that *instance* has the same properties as a non-template static function: *i.e.* that instance emanating from its corresponding compilation unit will be invisible to other compilation units, including the linker.

Comment: Interesting - does that mean that *static* has no effect here? Or does it change anything? Are the two functions even both correct / valid C++?

Comment: Template functions are automatically inlined. In C++, inline not only hints compiler to inline, but also forbids its inclusion to symbols table. Inline in C++ have about the same meaning as C99's `static inline`. So, here should be no difference.