# How to make the struct pointer point to a static char array

Tags: c, function, pointers, static, return

In the below piece of code, function returns an uninitialized pointer.

```
static abc* xyz(int a)                
{
    abc *z; 
    return(z);
}
```

How to modify this function, so that this pointer point to a static char array. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Show the declaration of `abc`?

Comment: What is the use of `int a` parameter ?

Comment: typedef struct abc {
    int h;
    int d;
    char *r;
} abc;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question (*little weird, IMHO*) correctly, what you want is something like (*[with VLA support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)*)

```
static abc* xyz(int a)      //int a is unused here              
{
    abc *z = NULL; 
    static char buf[sizeof(abc)];  //static char array

    z = abc;

    return z;
}
```

---

**NOTE:** FWIW, the `static` is not the "storage class" for function return type or value. It does not mean that the function has to have a `static` variable as the expression with `return` statement.

Rather, this is the part of the function definition (*declaration-specifiers*, to be precise), to indicate that the function has internal llinkgae. In other words, the visibility of the function is limited to that particular translation unit only.

Related, from `C11`, chapter §6.9.1, *Function definitions Syntax*

> function-definition:
>   *declaration-specifiers declarator declaration-list<sub>opt</sub> compound-statement*

and

> The storage-class specifier, if any, in the declaration specifiers shall be either `extern` or `static`.

then, chapter §6.2.2, paragraph 3,

> If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage-class specifier `static`, the identifier has internal linkage.

<sup>If the above note makes sense, [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/558122/2173917) will also do, *maybe* in a better way</sup>

After this note, I think you would like to have a *corrected* version of the previous code, which looks like,

```
static abc* xyz(int a)      //int a is unused here              
{
    abc *z = NULL;
     //some code
    z = malloc(sizeof(*z)); //sanity check TODO
     //some more code
    return z;
}
```

only thing, you need to `free()` the returned pointer once you're done using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static local variable like this:

```
static abc* xyz(int a){
  static abc z;
  return &z;
}
```