# whys is void written after static in java method call

Tags: static, void

why is a `void` written after `static keyword` in a function definition?

I tried writing a void before static keyword.

It's giving me an error and displaying a message.

> volatile is expecte

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to C or C++, so that is simply the startard that defines it, and it makes an easier life to the people who write the parser for the compiler (they don't have to guess the order of keywords).

In relation to using the languages as a programer: `void` refers to the return type of the function and is a part of the function declaration just like its name and parameters. The `static` keyword says different things in each language. In a nutshell, in C it means that the function is visible only in that file, in C++ (and Java) is says that the function does not need the `this` and can be called on the Class itself (without an instance). For more info in this issue read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558122/what-is-a-static-function)

Answer (score 0):

See,it's a standard in any language where `static` tells that this function can be accessed from anywhere and `void` tells that this function is not returning anything and also as `void` is a return type and return type is always written just before function name therefore, you cant put `static` in between,you have to write it before.i hope you understand

Comment: so why its giving me an error "volatile" is expected

Answer (score 0):

`void` is a keyword for defining the method's return type.  In the case of `void` it's simply saying the method won't return anything.  You can put other things (`int`, `String`, etc.) there, but they have to reflect what you want to return (and you should get an error if you have code paths that won't return).

The reason `void` needs to be after `static` is because that's what the language defines.  The return type comes before the method's name.  You're getting an error because you're defining the method in a way the compiler isn't expecting.