# Why can an int return type function return a string?

Tags: c, string, return, return-type, boolean-expression

This is the function I'm talking about:

```
static int getInput()
{
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    return fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != NULL;
}
```

How does this work? Why can an int return type use fgets like this?

Comment: It doesn't return a string. `(fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != NULL)` is an `int` whose value is either 1 or 0

Comment: How it works? It does not, unless `input` is a global variable.

Comment: Please take a few hours to read the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book

Comment: Thank you for recommending this book, it seems amazing. I will definitely go through it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "*Why can an `int` return type function return a string?*"

In fact, It can´t.

Let´s take a closer look at this statement:

```
return fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin) != NULL;
```

`fgets()` returns a pointer to `char`. This pointer is checked for a null pointer. The validation of this boolean expression either evaluates to `1` if the returned pointer is a non-null pointer (`fgets()` actually returned a pointer to `input`) or `0` if it is a null pointer - means an error occurred at consuming input by the use of `fgets()`.

This `int` value (`0` or `1`) is then returned from the function `getInput()`; not a pointer or even a string by value itself (which is impossible regarding the C syntax).

---

Side notes:

1. `input` seems to be a global `char` array. Avoid global arrays. It can confuse you and readers. Pass a pointer to the buffer by reference and also pass the size of the buffer by value instead.

   ```
   static char* getInput (char* buf, size_t len)
   {
       if ( len > INT_MAX || len < 2 )
       {
           return NULL;
       }

       printf("Enter your name: ");
       return fgets(buf, len, stdin);
   }
   ```

   and call it like:

   ```
   char a[20];
   if ( getInput(a, sizeof(a)) == NULL )
   {
       fputs("Error occured at consuming input!", stderr);
   }
   ```
2. For the meaning of the `static` qualifer in this example, take a look at:

   [What is a "static" function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558122/what-is-a-static-function-in-c)

Comment: "and also pass the size of the buffer by value instead" --> note that `fgets()` curiously takes an `int` size.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That´s weird. I always use the `sizeof` operator at the second argument. Anyway, I want to use `sizeof()` to determine the size of the array at runtime. Should I implement an explicit cast?

Comment: Typicallly calling `fgets()` with a `sizeof` results in a compile time constant in `int` range, hence no warning or issue.  As a function `getInput (char* buf, size_t len)` uses the more sensible `size_t`, but no longer a constant and theoretically outside `int` range.  Alternatives: use `if (len < 0) return NULL;` or `assert(len >= 0 && (unsigned) len < SIZE_MAX);` or `getInput (char* buf, int len)` or  others

Comment: Oh and Oops, thinko with "runtime".

Comment: "What will happen if sizeof(a) > INT_MAX (even if unlikely)? "  --> A good SO question.  I would say that the `len` of `size_t len` would convert in an implementation specific manner to `int`.  Recall C has "An implementation shall support text files with lines containing at least 254 characters, including the terminating new-line character." so input line input more than 254 begins other issues.

Comment: Unfortunately I deleted my previous comment. I´ll try to revive it for reference: - I've thought about the latter (`getInput (char* buf, int len)`) but I am insecure. What will happen if `sizeof(a) > INT_MAX` (even unlikely) at the call to `getInput`? Will the `size_t` be automatically truncated to a compile time constant in `int` range like at the call to `fgets()` or will it be UB?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Can I ask you why you proposed `if (len < 0) return NULL;` as alternative or was it just a typo/thinko and you meant `if (len == 0)` or even better `if (len < 2)` instead? AFAIK `sizeof()` will not return a negative value.

Comment: [re:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62171538/why-can-an-int-return-type-function-return-a-string/62173143?noredirect=1#comment109996106_62173143) If function signature changed to `char* buf, int len`, then `if (len < 0) return NULL;` test could be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
fgets(...) != NULL
```

This evaluates to a boolean and a boolean is represented as an integer in C.

Comment: Ah, thank you. It confused me because it also works without the "!= NULL". Now I see how that makes sense.

Comment: @roseScarlett Without the comparison you should get some warning from your compiler.

Comment: Without the explicit comparison it's the same thing, as `if (ptr != NULL) {...}` is the same as `if (ptr) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Your function will either return `true == 1` or `false == 0`
This should not return a string

Comment: Thank you! I see it now. That string shows up later in the program, so I thought that this somehow returns it.

Comment: @roseScarlett: "That string shows up later"... because it's a global variable. If you can avoid global variables, you tend to prevent big headaches in tge future.

Answer (score -1):

Actually OPs function does not return `char *` pointer but it is possible to do so

```
int foo(char *c)
{
    return (int)c;
}
```

it will return char pointer converted to int. if the int is big enough to accommodate the pointer it is possible to convert it back to the pointer.

https://godbolt.org/z/z_xsc7

This kind of conversions is in a very common use in the microcontroller and very low level hardware related programming (when portability does not matter). Unsigned integers are used (usually fixed size like `uint64_t` to make sure they are big enough) to get, pass and store the addresses

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think something like this would be that common, but you learn something new every day.