# Should static declarations go in a header file

Tags: c

For public functions I'll put those in a header file such as:

```
// tree.h
bool TreeIsEmpty(const Tree *ptree);
bool TreeIsFull(const Tree *ptree);
size_t TreeItemCount(const Tree *ptree);
```

However, what about internal implementation items? Do those only go in my `tree.c` file or do I also put those into my `tree.h` file? For example, let's say for `TreeItemCount` I have a prototype such as:

```
// tree.c
static bool TreeItemCountInternal(const Tree *ptree);
```

Do I do anything in the header file with that?

Comment: do you mean *declarations* of static functions?  (Function definitions contain the function body)

Comment: No, you don't. If they're static, exposing them outside the file that defines them is meaningless at best and error prone at worst

Comment: @M.M yes sorry I mean putting the declaration in the header file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to declare `TreeItemCountInternal` without designating it as static:

```
bool TreeItemCountInternal(const Tree *ptree);
```

then you could put the forward declaration in the header file, and `#include` that header in you `.c` files. You might consider doing that if your project spans multiple `.c` files and you need to share a function across them. The `static` declaration, when applied to a function, limits it's scope to the *translation unit* in which it was declared (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558122/what-is-a-static-function-in-c) for an excellent explanation of what that means from a practical perspective).

Remember that one of the first steps your compiler takes when building a program is to take all of your `#include` directives, find the file in quesetion, and paste it's contents in place of the `#include` statement.

There is no dogmatic rule that says you should always put the declaration in the header (although it's often good practice), and the act of doing so-- in and of itself-- does not confer any particular benefit or status (but it could make a lot of difference, depending on how the rest of the program is structured).

Answer (score 2):

`static bool TreeItemCountInternal(...);` has [internal linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage), so you wouldn't put anything in the header file.

Comment: I see. Even so, it's not helpful to show the full declarations of the `c` file in the header? Or is that not the way it works.