# Expose c-function for testing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a c-function within a class:

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject
@end

@implementation MyClass 
static void MyFunction(void) {
// Do some stuff.
}
@end
```

And I'd like to expose my function for testing:

```
@interface MyClass (testing)
static void MyFunction(void);
@end
```

But this leads to error:

> Function 'MyFunction' has internal linkage but is not
> definedclang(-Wundefined-internal)

Is there some way to expose this method?

Comment: Just removing `static` keyword should make your sample work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a "static" function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558122/what-is-a-static-function-in-c)