# What is external linkage and internal linkage?

Tags: c++, c++-faq

I want to understand the external linkage and internal linkage and their difference.

I also want to know the meaning of

> `const` variables internally link by default unless otherwise declared as `extern`.

Answer (score 391, accepted):

When you write an implementation file (`.cpp`, `.cxx`, etc) your compiler generates a **translation unit**. This is the source file from your implementation plus all the headers you `#include`d in it.

*Internal linkage* refers to everything only **in scope of a translation unit**.

*External linkage* refers to things that exist beyond a particular translation unit. In other words, **accessible through the whole program**, which is the combination of all translation units (or object files).

Comment: I'd upvote this except for one glitch: A translation unit is not "somehow the object file", it's the source code from which the compiler _creates_ the object file.

Comment: @FrankHB, what is the "something more important" that the answer is missing?

Comment: @Mathematician Sorry for late... I think the problem should be obvious (besides the accuracy of wording). This answer is incomplete, as the question about rule of `const` variables (as well as its purpose) is totally missed here.

Answer (score 367):

As [dudewat said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c/1358622#1358622) *external* linkage means the symbol (function or global variable) is accessible throughout your program and *internal* linkage means that it is only accessible in one [translation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_%28programming%29).

You can explicitly control the linkage of a symbol by using the `extern` and `static` keywords. If the linkage is not specified then the default linkage is `extern` (external linkage) for non-`const` symbols and `static` (internal linkage) for `const` symbols.

```
// In namespace scope or global scope.
int i; // extern by default
const int ci; // static by default
extern const int eci; // explicitly extern
static int si; // explicitly static

// The same goes for functions (but there are no const functions).
int f(); // extern by default
static int sf(); // explicitly static
```

Note that instead of using `static` (internal linkage), it is better to use [*anonymous* namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions) into which you can also put `class`es. Though they allow `extern` linkage, anonymous namespaces are unreachable from other translation units, making linkage *effectively* `static`.

```
namespace {
  int i; // extern by default but unreachable from other translation units
  class C; // extern by default but unreachable from other translation units
}
```

Comment: The implementation of the "export" keyword highlighted a difference between a function declared 'static' and a function declared in the unnamed namespace.  To summarise as best I can, an function template declared with the export keyword in one translation unit can refer to a function defined in an unnamed namespace of a different translation unit as a result of 2-phase lookup. (http://www.ddj.com/showArticle.jhtml?articleID=184401584)

Comment: What if I do following:

1.cpp

<code>const int ci;</code>

2.cpp

<code>extern const int ci;</code>

Comment: @Rajenda you will get an unresolved symbol error (sorry for the nine month delay in answering I missed this comment).

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the anonymous namespace. I didn't realize this feature before!

Comment: Info that might greatly enhance this answer: 1) static is not deprecated anymore in C++11. 2) anonymous namespace members in C++11 have internal linkage by default. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832940/why-are-functions-objects-inside-anonymous-namespace-have-external-linkage

Comment: @Klaim thanks I didn't notice that change in the standard, I removed the claim. Do you have a reference that using `static` is recommended over using unnamed namespaces?

Comment: @Motti I didn't say that. Also I think that's the other way around. From what I understand, the committee first deprecated static then had reasons to keep it that I don't know about; still anonymous namespace is more recomanded but I don't have a source about this.

Comment: @Richard Corden : the keyword "export" is considered deprecated in C++11

Comment: @incises:  Yes - good point.  The change is even more significant.  C++ '11 has changed the linkage of identifiers in an unnamed namespace to internal linkage.  So there is no real difference at all anymore.

Comment: What does it mean "external linkage but unreachable from other translation units"? How can it be unreachable but still external?

Comment: @szx, in C++98 you couldn't have a template [templated on an internal type](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8001047) for this purpose a type declared in an anonymous namespace was OK. I don't know if this distinction (external but unreachable) has any meaning in C++11.

Comment: @Motti: Is that the only difference?

Comment: @Motti : If static declaration makes it an internal linkage ,how can we acess the static variables anywhere inside a file ,please correct me if  i am getting it wrong .

Comment: @N.Nihar You can access it according to the regular C++ rules  (only after it has been declared and in the correct scope).

Comment: @Motti : If I declare a function like void a(); in file a.c, define it in b.c and finally call it from a.c, wouldn't it work (as declaration of function a() in file a.c is extern in linkage by default)? Apparently, as I do gcc a.c b.c, it gives error of undefined reference to a!

Comment: @Soumen, it sounds like it should work. Did you do all your decelerations and definitions in the global scope?

Comment: @Motti, everything is in global scope, i.e. definition of function main() in a.c, declaration of function a() in a.c and definition of function a() in b.c; these are the only functions used; function a() is called from main() in a.c;

Comment: @Soumen, I've just verified that it works as I describe it on gcc 4.4.7 (for both C and C++). If you're facing problems please post a question about it (the comments really aren't the place to do this)

Comment: Downvote because in C++ terminology, accessibility is totally different to linkage.

Comment: @incises The keyword `export` is [directly **removed** from C++11](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp03.temp), though it is reserved ([still as a keyword](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/lex.key#tab:keywords)) for future use. [Deprecated features](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/#depr) in C++ are totally different, which still **require to be implemented** by conforming implementations.

Comment: I would like to point out that `extern int a = 3;` would cause a warning with both `g++` and `clang++`. See [initialized and declared ‘extern’, why I'm seeing below warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58458484/initialized-and-declared-extern-why-im-seeing-below-warning) for explanations.

Comment: This and many other answers state that global variables are `extern` by default and leave it at that. Even though this is true, `int i;` is **not** the same as `extern int i;` as the examples imply because global variables are also automatically defined in C++. So `int i;` is actually the same as `extern int i{};`, which may explain why `int i;` and `extern int i;` exhibit different behavior in your test program. See https://www.goldsborough.me/c/c++/linker/2016/03/30/19-34-25-internal_and_external_linkage_in_c++

Answer (score 141):

- A global variable has *external linkage* by default. Its scope can be extended to files other than containing it by giving a matching `extern` declaration in the other file.
- The scope of a global variable can be restricted to the file containing its declaration by prefixing the declaration with the keyword `static`. Such variables are said to have *internal linkage*.

Consider following example:

### 1.cpp

```
void f(int i);
extern const int max = 10;
int n = 0;
int main()
{
    int a;
    //...
    f(a);
    //...
    f(a);
    //...
}
```

1. The signature of function `f` declares `f` as a function with *external linkage* (default). Its definition must be provided later in this file or in other translation unit (given below).
2. `max` is defined as an integer constant. The default linkage for constants is *internal*. Its linkage is changed to external with the keyword `extern`. So now `max` can be accessed in other files.
3. `n` is defined as an integer variable. The default linkage for variables defined outside function bodies is *external*.

### 2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern const int max;
extern int n;
static float z = 0.0;

void f(int i)
{
    static int nCall = 0;
    int a;
    //...
    nCall++;
    n++;
    //...
    a = max * z;
    //...
    cout << "f() called " << nCall << " times." << endl;
}
```

1. `max` is declared to have *external linkage*. A matching definition for `max` (with external linkage) must appear in some file. (As in 1.cpp)
2. `n` is declared to have *external linkage*.
3. `z` is *defined* as a global variable with *internal linkage*.
4. The definition of `nCall` specifies `nCall` to be a variable that retains its value across calls to function `f()`. Unlike local variables with the default auto storage class, `nCall` will be initialized only once at the first invocation of `f()`. The storage class specifier `static` affects the lifetime of the local variable and not its scope.

**NB:** The keyword `static` plays a double role. When used in the definitions of global variables, it specifies *internal linkage*. When used in the definitions of the local variables, it specifies that the lifetime of the variable is going to be the duration of the program instead of being the duration of the function.

Comment: Importantly, when used in the definitions of local variables, `static` allows lazy single initialization (which can be useful if you need a global-ish object but have to control when it is constructed due to issues with global construction order and can't dynamically allocate it using `new` while more in-depth initialization schemes may be beyond what is necessary for the object in question; by implication, this is mainly an issue on embedded systems that use C++).

Comment: Very Good Examle, made my day.

Comment: excellent answer!
it is worth pointing out that gloabl `const` variables have internal (static) linkage by default, it's only `non-const` global variables which have external linkage by default

Comment: yes i like this answer the best. Very good explanation using 1 and 2.cpp

Comment: Regarding Point 4: _Unlike local variables with the default auto storage class, nCall will be initialized only once at the start of the program ..._, I'd like to clarify that the _local_ static variable `nCall` will not be initialized upon program start but upon the first invocation of `f()`. And since C++17 (AFAIK), this initialization is required to be thread-safe!

Comment: Comment on "NB: ..." paragraph: The explanation implies that only one of the 2 roles are played depending on whether the static is used on global or local variables. But in both cases, I think all 2 roles are played (based on https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration), and it's just that one of the 2 roles is just so obvious.

Comment: @aniliitb10 This point is an important one. To declare a non-local/global `const` variable with external linkage, the `extern` keyword must be used *everywhere* that `const` variable is used (including in the file that provides the definition). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/extern-cpp?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 31):

### In terms of 'C' (Because static keyword has different meaning between 'C' & 'C++')

Lets talk about different scope in 'C'

SCOPE: It is basically how long can I see something and how far.

1. Local variable : Scope is only inside a function. It resides in the STACK area of RAM.
                   Which means that every time a function gets called all the variables
                   that are the part of that function, including function arguments are
                   freshly created and are destroyed once the control goes out of the
                   function. (Because the stack is flushed every time function returns)
2. Static variable: Scope of this is for a file. It is accessible every where in the file
                   in which it is declared. It resides in the DATA segment of RAM. Since
                   this can only be accessed inside a file and hence INTERNAL linkage. Any
                   other files cannot see this variable. In fact STATIC keyword is the 
                   only way in which we can introduce some level of data or function
                   hiding in 'C'
3. Global variable: Scope of this is for an entire application. It is accessible form every
                   where of the application. Global variables also resides in DATA segment
                   Since it can be accessed every where in the application and hence 
                   EXTERNAL Linkage

By default all functions are global.  In case, if you need to 
hide some functions in a file from outside, you can prefix the static 
keyword to the function. :-)

Comment: @Libin:

As for 1) local variables do not have to be on stack - they are usually on stack but can be in registers and in ARM environment they are more often in registers than on stack (depends on some factors - call level, number of formal args..)

Comment: @Libin: As for 1) If you consider 'flush' as overwrite - this is wrong. Stack pointer is just moved to different place. No 'previously valid local vars' are 'flushed'/cleared etc.

You mix variable scope with storage duration. Scope tells from where you can access a var. Storage duration tells how long it exists. You can have local variable with static storage duration. It means it lives "forever" but can be accessed from a function it is declared in.

Comment: Downvote for inaccurate concepts and obvious misconceptions. Strictly speaking, there is no "global" nor "variable" (as a noun) defined in C. You might probably want to refer "file scope object" rather than "global variable", but talking about "scope" (in C it is a property of an *identifier*) of it is nonsense. (Both terms are defined in C++ normatively with slightly different meanings.)

Comment: @Artur I think you´d forgot the "*only*" in "*It means it lives "forever" but can be accessed (only) from a function it is declared in.*" - This is an important detail, hence I would like to point that out explicitly.

Answer (score 23):

Before talking about the question, it is better to know the term [*translation unit*](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1), [*program*](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#1) and some [basic concepts](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.def) of C++ (actually linkage is one of them in general) precisely. You will also have to know what is a [scope](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope).

I will emphasize some key points, esp. those missing in previous answers.

*Linkage* is a property of a *name*, which is introduced by a *declaration*. Different names can denote same *entity* (typically, an object or a function). So talking about *linkage* of an entity is usually nonsense, unless you are sure that the entity will only be referred by the unique name from some specific declarations (usually one declaration, though).

Note an *object* is an entity, but a *variable* is not. While talking about the linkage of a variable, actually the name of the denoted entity (which is introduced by a specific declaration) is concerned. The linkage of the name is in one of the three: no linkage, internal linkage or external linkage.

Different translation units can share the same declaration by header/source file (yes, it is the standard's wording) inclusion. So you may refer the same name in different translation units. If the name declared has external linkage, the identity of the entity referred by the name is also shared. If the name declared has internal linkage, the same name in different translation units denotes different entities, but you can refer the entity in different scopes of the same translation unit. If the name has no linkage, you simply cannot refer the entity from other scopes.

(Oops... I found what I have typed was somewhat just repeating [the standard wording](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#2) ...)

There are also some other confusing points which are not covered by the language specification.

1. Visibility (of a name). It is also a property of declared name, but [with a meaning different to linkage](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#declarative-4).
2. [Visibility (of a side effect)](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/intro.multithread#intro.races-11). This is not related to this topic.
3. Visibility (of a symbol). This notion can be [used by actual implementations](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility). In such implementations, a symbol with specific visibility in object (binary) code is usually the target mapped from the entity definition whose names having the same specific linkage in the source (C++) code. However, it is usually not guaranteed one-to-one. For example, a symbol in a dynamic library image can be specified only shared in that image internally from source code (involved with some extensions, typically, `__attribute__` or `__declspec`) or compiler options, and the image is not the whole program or the object file translated from a translation unit, thus no standard concept can describe it accurately. Since symbol is not a normative term in C++, it is only an implementation detail, even though the related extensions of dialects may have been widely adopted.
4. Accessibility. In C++, this is usually about [property of class members or base classes](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/class.access), which is again a different concept unrelated to the topic.
5. Global. [In C++, "global" refers something of global namespace or global namespace scope.](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.namespace#3) The latter is roughly equivalent to *file scope* in the C language. Both in C and C++, the linkage has nothing to do with scope, although scope (like linkage) is also tightly concerned with an identifier (in C) or a name (in C++) introduced by some declaration.

The [linkage rule of namespace scope `const` variable](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.link#3) is something special (and particularly different to the `const` object declared in file scope in C language which also has the concept of linkage of identifiers). Since [ODR](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr) is enforced by C++, [it is important to keep no more than one definition of the same variable or function occurred in the whole program except for `inline` functions](http://www.eel.is/c++draft/basic.def.odr#4). If there is no such special rule of `const`, a simplest declaration of `const` variable with initializers (e.g. `= xxx`) in a header or a source file (often a "header file") included by multiple translation units (or included by one translation unit more than once, though rarely) in a program will violate ODR, which makes to use `const` variable as replacement of some object-like macros impossible.

Comment: This answer sounds very proficient and might be very exact (I cannot judge that) but most likely it is not as understandable as desired by many of the people looking up this question here instead of directly reading the language spec. At least for my needs I will stick with the accepted answer but still thank you for giving a small insight into the language spec. 

Answer (score 14):

I think [Internal and External Linkage in C++](http://www.goldsborough.me/c/c++/linker/2016/03/30/19-34-25-internal_and_external_linkage_in_c++/) gives a clear and concise explanation:

> A translation unit refers to an implementation (.c/.cpp) file and all
>   header (.h/.hpp) files it includes. If an object or function inside
>   such a translation unit has internal linkage, then that specific
>   symbol is only visible to the linker within that translation unit. If
>   an object or function has external linkage, the linker can also see it
>   when processing other translation units. The static keyword, when used
>   in the global namespace, forces a symbol to have internal linkage. The
>   extern keyword results in a symbol having external linkage.
>
> The compiler defaults the linkage of symbols such that:
>
> Non-const global variables have external linkage by default
>   Const global variables have internal linkage by default
>   Functions have external linkage by default

Answer (score 10):

**Basically**

- `extern linkage` variable is visible in all files
- `internal linkage` variable is visible in single file.

**Explain: const variables internally link by default unless otherwise declared as extern**

1. by default, global variable is `external linkage`
2. but, `const` global variable is `internal linkage`
3. extra, `extern const` global variable is `external linkage`

**A pretty good material about linkage in C++**

http://www.goldsborough.me/c/c++/linker/2016/03/30/19-34-25-internal_and_external_linkage_in_c++/

Answer (score 8):

Linkage determines whether identifiers that have identical names refer to the same object, function, or other entity, even if those identifiers appear in different translation units. The linkage of an identifier depends on how it was declared.
There are three types of linkages:

1. **Internal linkage** : identifiers can only be seen within a translation unit.
2. **External linkage** : identifiers can be seen (and referred to) in other translation units.
3. **No linkage** : identifiers can only be seen in the scope in which they are defined.
   Linkage does not affect scoping

*C++ only* : You can also have linkage between C++ and non-C++ code fragments, which is called **language linkage**.

Source :[IBM Program Linkage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/cplr080.htm)

Answer (score 2):

**In C++**

Any variable at file scope and that is not nested inside a class or function, is visible throughout all translation units in a program. This is called **external linkage** because at link time the name is visible to the linker everywhere, external to that translation unit.

**Global variables and ordinary functions have external linkage.**

**Static** object or function name  at file scope is local to translation unit. That is 
called as  **Internal Linkage**

Linkage refers only to elements that have addresses at link/load time; thus, class declarations and local variables have no linkage.

Comment: const global vars have internal linkage.