# Static vs global

Tags: c, static, global

If I have a C file like below, what is the difference between `i` and `j`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int i;
int j;

int main ()
{
    //Some implementation
}
```

Comment: Read answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c

Comment: [Difference between static, auto, global and local variable in the context of c and c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415321/difference-between-static-auto-global-and-local-variable-in-the-context-of-c-a)

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`i` has internal linkage so you can't use the name `i` in other source files (strictly translation units) to refer to the same object.

`j` has external linkage so you can use `j` to refer to this object if you declare it `extern` in another translation unit.

Comment: there shouldn't be a runtime difference if you are doing the same thing, as the compiler might generate the same code. Compilation might be slightly longer with a global though, since it has a wider scope.

Comment: Is it possible to programmatically determine the linkage of any arbitrary variable at compile time (potentially using compiler's extension) or at run time? See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65520719/9881330.

Comment: Why do I need to use "extern" to declare "j"? Does this mean that "int j;" is a defintion and not a declaration?

Answer (score 38):

`i` is not visible outside the module; `j` is globally accessible.

That is, another module, which is linked to it, can do

```
extern int j;
```

and then be able to read and write the value in `j`.  The same other module cannot access `i`, but could declare its own instance of it, even a global one—which is not visible to the first module.

Comment: Is the 'extern' declaration necessary?

Comment: It depends on the implementation.  Use of `extern` is guaranteed to not cause trouble, provided one module has the symbol as non-`extern` and public (which allocates it).  Early Unix implementations merged symbols with the same name—much like a Fortran common—so `extern` was not required.

Comment: Note that "Not visible" doesn't mean its out of scope. That means that if you would declare an i in a different compilation unit and you would remove the static i from your .c file the global i would be visible to your .c file. In contrast, if the global i were out of scope it wouldn't matter if you would have a static i declared in your .c file. The global one would never be visible. static i taking precedence over a global i defined in another compilation unit is called 'shadowing'. It also happens with function locals and is not a c++/c-only thing.

Answer (score 7):

The difference is that `i` has internal linkage, and `j` has external linkage. This means you can access `j` from other files that you link with, whereas `i` is only available in the file where it is declared.

Answer (score 5):

`i` will have **static linkage**, i.e., the variable is accessible in the current file only.

`j` should be defined as `extern`, that is

```
extern int j;
```

in another header file (`.h`), and then it will have **external linkage**, and can be accessed across files.

Answer (score 4):

Scope of static variable/function is within the same file despite you include the  file as part of a different source file.

Scope of global variable is throughout the files in which it is included. To include the variable in a different source file, we use `extern` before the variable declaration. No memory is allocated again for the variable in this case.

`extern` is used to declare a C variable without defining it. `extern` keyword extends the visibility of the C variables and C functions. Since functions are visible through out the program by default, the use of `extern` is not needed in function declaration/definition. Its use is redundant.