# Why can't a non-static variable reside in a header file?

Tags: c++, variables, static, header

Take for example:

```
// myheader.h
static int myStaticVar = 0;
// If we remove 'static' the compiler will throw linker error.

void DoStuff();

// and myheader.cpp, and main.cpp;  etc
```

This is how I would explain it:

> Static variables do not have external linkage, and when we compile
>   without 'static' we are "including" the static variable (which is
>   global here) in every file, which create duplicates and linker will
>   throw an error since multiple declaration is not allowed.

Is there any better way to explain this? Thanks.

PS: Are we suppose to have static variables (not talking about members) in header file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why can't a non-static variable reside in a header file?

Because it breaks the **[One Definition Rule(ODR)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)**.
When you include the header file containing a non-static variable, the declaration of the variable gets pasted in each source file where it is included. Thus, you end up having more than one definition of a variable, in the same **[Translation Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)**, this violates the ODR, and hence, the linker will give you linking errors.

> How to explain static variables declared in header files?

When you declare a static variable in a header file, a copy of the variable gets created in each **[Translation Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)** where the header file is included.

Declaring a static variable in the header file will not give you multiple definition errors, but it does not achieve your purpose of having a global variable whose value is shared across all files which access it.

You may think that since you are using a global static variable, its value will be retained across different files, but as mentioned above, each Translation Unit has its own copy of the variable, and it does not achieve what you think you are achieving.

> Are we suppose to have static variables (not talking about members) in header file?

**No, Never!**

> How do you declare and define global variables?

You need to use the `extern` keyword.

Add the extern declaration of the variable in a header file. The header should be included by the one source file that defines the variable, and by all the source files that reference the variable. **Only one** source file **should define** the variable. Also, only one header file should declare the variable.

**filename.h**

```
extern int gVariable;  /* Declaration */
```

**file1.cpp**

```
#include "filename.h"  

/* Definition */ 
int gVariable = 37;    

void doSomething(void) 
{ 
    return gVariable++; 
}
```

**file2.cpp**

```
#include "filename.h" 
#include <stdio.h>  
void doSomethingWithGlobal(void) 
{     
    printf("Global variable: %d\n", gVariable++); 
}
```

Comment: And to have a variable in the header, one should use `extern int foo;` and then define the variable in only one of the TUs.

Comment: To correct the answer here. You won't have multiple definitions in the same translation unit. You will have multiple definitions across **multiple** translation units, so at link-time ODR is violated because the linker does not know which to use.

Comment: @void.pointer: It also leads to toolchain-specific solutions, such as "weak" symbols or selectany behavior (which every toolchain has to implement to support templated symbols, but there's no standard/portable way to invoke that behavior for arbitrary variables)

Answer (score 1):

First, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837190/c-c-global-vs-static-global/7837369#7837369) to a similar question.

To complement the answer based on your question, here goes:

When you `#include` a file (any file, `.h` files is a common convention), **it almost basically just copy-pastes it in your code**. If you have non-static variable in the header file and you include it in two source files, **the variable gets copy-pasted in both source files** and well you get a link error as I explained in the answer I told you to read above.

If you want to share a global variable across many source files, you should do this:

In **only one** of your source files:

```
type global_var = default_value;
```

In the header file:

```
extern type global_var;
```

So, this way, all the source files see there is going to be a `global_var` somewhere in the bunch of source files. Only one of the source files actually contains that variable and when linking happens, all the source files would be referring to that one instance of `global_var`

Answer (score 0):

The header file (.h) tells you (declares) what the definition file (.cpp) will do.

For a metaphor - a header file is like to telling a lot of friends that you are going to do something, but in reality you are going to do it once.