# static declaration of m follows non-static declaration

Tags: c

I am trying a small example to know about the static external variable and its uses. The static variable is of local scope and the external variable is of global scope.

**static5.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "static5.h"
static int m = 25;
int main(){
 func(10);
 return 0;
}
```

**static5.h**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int func(val){
 extern int m;
 m = m + val;
 printf("\n value is : %d \n",m);
}
```

**gcc static5.c static5.h**

**o/p :**

```
static5.c:3: error: static declaration of m follows non-static declaration
static5.h:3: note: previous declaration of m was here
```

**EDITED**

The correct program :

```
a.c:
#include<stdio.h>
#include "a1_1.h"
int main(){
 func(20);
 return 0;
}

a1.h:
static int i = 20;

a1_1.h:
#include "a1.h"
int func(val){
 extern int i;
 i = i + val;
 printf("\n i : %d \n",i);
}
```

This works fine perfectly fine. But this is compiled into a single compilation unit. Hence could able to access the static variable . Across the compilation unit we cannot use the static variable by using the extern variable.

Comment: Shouldn't the `extern int m;` be outside the function-body?

Comment: m is declared as static  in static5.c and hence the scope is within the file.so the error.

Comment: So what is the question? m is static to the static5.c file, so it can't be accessed anywhere else even declaring it with `extern`

Comment: It's unusual and potentially dangerous to have any function definitions in a header file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remember this (quoting Eli Bendersky):

> - A static variable inside a function keeps its value between
>     invocations.
> - A static global variable or a function is "seen" only in
>     the file it's declared in

In your code, `static int m = 25;` means that `m`'s *scope is limited only to that file*, that is, it is only visible inside `static5.c` and nowhere else.

If you would like to make use of `m` outside of `static5.c` make sure to remove the keyword `static` from the declaration of the variable.

For a more canonical explanation, along with an example, see [this answer by Eli Bendersky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/572550/1426969)

**EDIT: (according to Klas' recommendation)** **The actual scope is a compilation unit, not the source file. *The compilation unit is the way the file looks after the preprocessor step*

Comment: The scope is compilation unit, not source file. The compilation unit is the way the file looks after the preprocessor step, and then func is in the same file.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck Thanks for the remark! I am gonna update my answer.

Comment: @NlightNFortis: Its one compilation unit only. I do gcc static5.c and static5.h. the code is compiled into single compilation unit. But still I got the error.

Comment: @Angus Yes the *preprocessor* changes the `include "static5.h"` inside static5.c with the source code of that file, so the error messages denote that when it comes the time for the actual compilation, the compiler finds a `non-static` declaration of m (the one inside the func inside `static5.h`) before it finds the static one (inside the `static5.c` file).

Comment: Where is a static variable inside a function actually stored ? Is it also stored in `.data` like a regular global variable?

Answer (score 21):

`static` has a very simple logic to it. If a variable is `static`, it means that it is a global variable, but it's scope is limited to where it is defined (i.e. only visible there). For example:

- Outside a function: global variable but visible only within the file (actually, the compilation unit)
- Inside a function: global variable but visible only within the function
- (C++) Inside a class: global variable but visible only to the class

Now let's see what the C11 standard says regarding `static` and `extern` (emphasis mine):

> 6.2.2.3
>
> If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storage-class specifier `static`, the identifier has internal linkage.
>
> 6.2.2.4
>
> *For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, **if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration.*** If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.
>
> 6.2.2.7
>
> **If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.**

So the standard says that first, if you have:

```
static int m;
extern int m;
```

then the second declaration (with `extern`) would regard the first one and in the end `m` would still be `static`.

However, in any other case, if there are declarations with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined. This actually leaves us with only one option:

```
extern int m;
static int m;
```

i.e., `extern` declaration before `static` declaration. gcc was nice enough to give you error in this case of **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the nice explanation. But it baffles me that one would use `static` and `extern` together - it seems to speak to me "I want var a to associate with this file only (static) and I would expose it (extern) to all other files". It sounds conflicting. Am I correct with my understanding? If not, when would one would need to use both `static` and `extern` together? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @unheilig, true in your personal project, but it's not without merit in general. In the case of `static` before `extern`, imagine a library with the usual header files with extern function declarations. You could override some of those functions by declaring them as `static` before including the header. A sort of compile-time-enabled `valgrind` for example could be possible with this method.

Comment: The other way is probably problematic because after the `extern` declaration, the compiler would generate code to be linked to that declaration, but later you say it was supposed to be `static`, so the compiler has to go back and fix the previous code. Since C compilers are single-pass, this is annoying at best.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is exactly as stated in the error message. `m` is declared a normal `int` but is later defined as a `static int`.

`extern` tells the compiler/linker to look for the variable in the global table of variables.

`static` (outside a functon) tells the compiler to exclude the variable from the global table of variables.

Do you see the conflict?

To fix the problem, either remove the `static` keyword from the definition or move the definition above the inclusion of `static5.h`.

It should be noted that the way you have designed your files is not considered best practice. Include files don't usually contain functions.

Comment: I thought so at first too, but the standard is more flexible on that. If the `static` declaration comes before the `extern` declaration, it is perfectly ok. See my answer for references. Only problem is if the `extern` declaration comes first.

Comment: @Shahbaz Thanks for the clarification. I was not sure whether the extern declaration would be erroneous of simply superfluous.

Answer (score 2):

remove the keyword static while declaring m and the errors will be removed and you will be able to get the answer as 50. The static keyword makes the scope to restrict within the file.