# extern and global variables with the same name in C

Tags: c, global, external, extern

I'm trying to figure out what happens if in some program we'll have like that:

```
extern int x;

void foo(){...}
void bar(){...}

void main(){
foo();
bar();
}
int x=0;
```

So what is suppose to happen?Why is it allowed to have two such variables with the same name?are they different?

Comment: Try compiling: `int x;
int x;
int x = 3;
extern int x;`.  Even with very fussy options set for GCC, it compiles.  Move the `extern` line to the top and `clang -Weverything` accepts it.  The first two `int x;` are tentative definitions.  The `int x = 3;` is a non-tentative (definitive?) definition.  You couldn't repeat that, or use a different initializer.  If there was no definitive definition by the end of the file, the `int x;` would be converted into one.

Comment: A variable declared at file scope with no storage-class specifier has the same storage class and linkage as one explictly declared `extern`.  That is, there's no distinction between the kind of variables you're calling "extern" and the kind you're calling "global".  The presence or absence of `extern` can make a difference in other ways, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not "two" variables. They are the *same*.

```
extern int x;
```

is a declaration of `x`.

and

```
int x=0;
```

provides the definition for `x`. This is perfectly fine and valid.

---

You can have multiple declarations like:

```
extern int x;
extern int x;
```

too and it'll compile as well.

Note when you are providing the multiple declarations for the same identifier, the rules are somewhat complex. See: [6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.2) for details.
See [static declaration of m follows non-static declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17041571/4389800) for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Perfectly fine. 
This

```
extern int x;
```

only declares the variable x of type int and extern explictly says, that it will be defined at an another location.

In your case , a few lines below

```
int x = 0;
```

Here is a link for more info on extern -> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

> **The extern specifier is only allowed in the declarations of variables
>   and functions** (except class members or function parameters). It
>   specifies external linkage, and does not technically affect storage
>   duration, but it cannot be used in a definition of an automatic
>   storage duration object, so all extern objects have static or thread
>   durations. **In addition, a variable declaration that uses extern and
>   has no initializer is not a definition**.

Answer (score 2):

"extern" means:
 *"this variable will come from some other place. It is not being declared here; this statement just provides notice that it is a valid name."*

So in essence this code is:

```
extern int x;
// This is a valid name, but the variable will be defined "externally", eg, somewhere else.

[...] 

int x=0;
// OH!  Here is where the definition is.  Now we know where that "extern" variable came from.
// And we know that it starts with value 0.
```

It is somewhat unusual for and `extern` and definition to appear in the same file.

More typically, the definition is in one `.C` file, and the `extern` is in a different `.C` that will get linked together during the build process.

Comment: more typically the `extern` is in a header file