# global declarations/initializations using static, const, constexpr

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++ or C++11, for the following declarations//initializations,

```
// global scope
const int a = 1; // line 1
static const int b = 2; // line 2
constexpr int c = 3;  // line 3
static constexpr int d = 4; // line 4
constexpr int e = a + b + c*d; // line 5
static constexpr int f = a - b - c*d; // line 6
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3709207/c-semantics-of-static-const-vs-const) says at file scope there is no difference between line 1 and 2 in C++.
How about line 3 and 4?

Are there differences between line 4 and 5?

Are there differences between line 5 and 6?

Comment: "What does all this code mean" is an awfully broad question.  A book is probably your best destination if you don't know what `const` or `static` or `constexpr` means.

Comment: That's a useful edit, although the code here is not the same as the code in the question you link to.  I'm *guessing* that you're either pursuing an open-ended discussion about variable declarations, or you're asking what `static` means.

Comment: According to my understanding, `static` means the variable exists until the end of the program, but when put `static` together with `constant` or `constexpr` in global scope, `static` doesn't add additional meaning to the variable when the variable is initialized only with `const` or `constexpr`.

Comment: Without picking word meanings apart, I think you understand what `static` means in the context of a function body, but you don't know [what it means when applied to variables that would otherwise be global](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271902/static-vs-global).

Comment: The link you gave talks about linkage and file scope. But `const` or `constexpr` has default internal linkage, so `static` doesn't add any meaning to the variable which have been declared by `const` or `constexpr` like line 3 and 5, so my understanding is that line 3 and 4 have no differences, neither do line 5 and 6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there should not be any difference (aside from their values of course) because constexpr and const implies internal linkage:

> `[C++11: 3.5/3]:` **A name having namespace scope** (3.3.6) **has internal linkage if it is the name of**
>
> - a variable, function or function template that is explicitly declared `static`; or,
> - **a variable that is explicitly declared** `const` or **`constexpr`** and **neither explicitly declared `extern` nor previously declared to have external linkage**; or
> - a data member of an anonymous union.

Answer (score 0):

`static` variables exist for the lifetime of the program `static` is useful for functions like this:

```
void func (int i) {
    int var = i;
}
```

when a function is finish executing its code its objects destroys automatically 
to prevent this you can use `static`

```
void func (int i) {
   static int var = i;
}
```

this mean that when a function finish executing its code the object defined as static will remain until the program ends

`const` applies for variables, and prevents them from being modified in your code.
 and `constexpr` are used for constant expressions this two is read-only it means that once you initialize a value it cannot be modified

the difference of this two is:

```
static constexpr int d = 4; // line 4
constexpr int e = a + b + c*d;
```

in `static constexpr int d = 4` is we define a variable named d that is a static constant expression integer and have a value of 4 and cannot be modified and remain until the program ends

and in `constexpr int e = a + b + c*d;` is we define a variable name e that is 
constant expression integer that have a value depends on what the result in those operations and cannot be modified