# Unresolved external symbol - IdnToAscii

Tags: c++, linker, visual-studio-2012, idn

I tried to build the following sample application available on msdn:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319089%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I created a new C++ command line project in Visual Studio 2012 Premium on a windows 7 64bit box, and copied the code of the sample in the main cpp file.

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__IdnToAscii@20
```

From [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598181/error-lnk2001-unresolved-external-symbol) of people having similar errors, I figure I'm supposed to include some header or lib file. But which one(s)? How do I do that in VS2012/C++ (I'm a complete c++ noob...)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you need to link against `Normaliz.dll`.

Try adding `Normaliz.lib` in Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies

[image]

Comment: Could you kindly tell me how to achieve this in VS 2012?

Comment: I would first search whether `Normaliz.dll` exists on the system. If yes, then see whether linker has the path to look into where this dll resides.