# Difference between local/block-scope declaration of function with extern and without it

Tags: c++, scope, extern, linkage, function-declaration

It appears that in C++ `extern` (NOT followed by a language-linkage string literal) makes no difference on function declarations at namespace scope ([Difference between declaration of function with extern and without it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866576/difference-between-declaration-of-function-with-extern-and-without-it)).  But does it have any effect whatsoever on block scope function declarations?  Or is a local function declaration without `extern` always equivalent to one with `extern`?

```
namespace {
  void f() {
     extern void g(); // has external linkage
     g();
  }
  void f2() {
     void g();        // always the same, as if, without extern
     g();
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you declare a function within a function? What do you think it does?

Comment: The opposite of extern is static - `static void g();  // internal linkage`.

Comment: @underscore_d check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034606/is-there-any-use-for-local-function-declarations

Comment: @EulersRainbow Thanks for that! Seems very niche but semantically valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules here come from [basic.link]:

> The name of a function declared in block scope and the name of a variable declared by a block scope `extern`
>   declaration have linkage. If there is a visible declaration of an entity with linkage having the same name and
>   type, ignoring entities declared outside the innermost enclosing namespace scope, the block scope declaration
>   declares that same entity and receives the linkage of the previous declaration. If there is more than one such
>   matching entity, the program is ill-formed. Otherwise, if no matching entity is found, the block scope entity
>   receives external linkage.

So there is no difference between a block scope function declaration with and without `external`. But note the interesting example:

> ```
> static void f();
>
> void g() {
>     extern void f(); // internal linkage
> }
> ```

Here, the block scope `f` redeclares `::f` and receives its same linkage: internal. Even though it's marked `extern`. But the presence of absence of the `extern` keyword is immaterial

Answer (score 1):

Whether a function has the extern specifier or not in any case it has external linkage (if it is not explicitly declared as having internal linkage).

However a local function declaration can hide other function declarations with the same name in the outer scope.

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

void f( int ) { std::cout << "F( int )" << std::endl; }
void f( short ) { std::cout << "f( short )" << std::endl; }

int main() 
{
    void f( short );

    f( 10 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
f( short )
```

If to comment the local declaration then the output will be

```
F( int )
```

Comment: I feel that this answer highlights the use of local function declarations more than answering whether there are any scenarios that the presence or absence of extern on a local function declaration matters?  Or am I missing something?  Also any references to the C++ standard will be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: @EulersRainbow A local declaration can be useful when there is a conflict between your function declaration and a declaration of a function with the same name in some library that is when the name resolution is ambiguios. As for the reference to the Standard unfortunately I have no  copy of the Standard or its draft by hand.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I understand their benefit - and your example does a great job of highlighting the benefit of local declarations.  But the question I am more interested in is: Based on the C++ standard, is their truly no difference ever if I add 'extern' to the local function declaration?

Comment: @EulersRainbow It has a difference for object declarations.

Comment: @EulersRainbow The default linkage for functions is `extern`. This fact is not affected by where the functions are declared. Perhaps this answer should say that more explicitly.