# extern on a static function in C++

Tags: c++, function, extern

I don't know why this is driving me nuts but it is. I have a function defined and forward declared in main.

```
static void myFunc(int x);

static void myFunc( int x)
{
   //do stuff
}

main()
```

I want to use myFunc(int x) in another class. So I would think all I have to do is
extern static void myFunc(int x) within that classes header and then just call it where I need to in the class definition, but it won't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot use extern and static together they are mutually exclusive.

`static` means **Internal Linkage**
`extern` means **External Linkage**

You need to use only `extern` if you need External Linkage.

Good Read:
**[what is external linkage and internal linkage in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c)**

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, but when I remove the static from the definition, it still will not build.

Comment: If you maintain the declaration as `static void myFunc(int);` the function *will be* `static` regardless of the presence of `static` in the definition.

Comment: Thanks, I have it, I removed the static, and also I had it declared wrong in the header.

Comment: @DixonSteel:You remove the `static` keyword from both the **declaration** and **definition** of the function, and then you can access it using `extern` from another source file(Translation Unit actually)