# Internal type as a template argument

Tags: c++, templates

ISO 98/03 standard (section 14.3.1) seems to forbid using a type with internal linkage as a template parameter. (See example below.) The C++11 standard does not.
G++ - using the old standard - is allowing it.
Am I misreading the 03 standard, or is g++ just letting this slide?

```
namespace
{
    struct hidden { };
}

template<typename T>
struct S
{
   T t;
};

int main()
{
    S<hidden> s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which g++ version? Might be an extension

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're correct that C++03 doesn't allow using a type with internal linkage as a template type parameter, while C++11 does.

I seem to recall, however, that definitions inside the anonymous namespace still have external linkage.

---

Yup, section 3.5 `[basic.link]` says

> A name having namespace scope (3.3.5) has internal linkage if it is the name of
>
> - an object, reference, function or function template that is explicitly declared static or,
> - an  object  or  reference  that  is  explicitly  declared `const` and neither  explicitly declared `extern` nor previously declared to have external linkage; or
> - a data member of an anonymous union.
>
> A name having namespace scope has external linkage if it is the name of
>
> - an object or reference, unless it has internal linkage; or
> - a function, unless it has internal linkage; or
> - a named class (clause 9), or an unnamed class defined in a typedef declaration in which the class has the typedef name for linkage purposes (7.1.3); or
> - a named enumeration (7.2), or an unnamed enumeration defined in a typedef declaration in which the enumeration has the typedef name for linkage purposes (7.1.3); or
> - an enumerator belonging to an enumeration with external linkage; or
> - a template, unless it is a function template that has internal linkage (clause 14); or
> - a namespace (7.3), unless it is declared within an unnamed namespace.

You have a named class at namespace scope, it has external linkage.

And the footnote on the bottom of page 115 of ISO/IEC 14882:2003 clarifies:

> Although entities in an unnamed namespace might have external linkage, they are effectively qualified by a name unique to their translation unit and therefore can never be seen from any other translation unit.

If you have another version, try looking in section 7.3.1.1 `[namespace.unnamed]`

Answer (score 4):

That's not a valid example of the rule. The `hidden` class in your example has *external* linkage. (It has a compiler-generated unique name such that nothing outside the current translation unit can actually link with it, but it's still external.)

The standard gives an example of a local type:

```
template <class T> class X { /* ... */ };
void f()
{
  struct S { /* ... */ };

  X<S> x3;  // error: local type used as template-argument
  X<S*> x4; // error: pointer to local type used as template-argument
}
```