# extern function prototype and static definition

Tags: c, macos, gcc, freeglut

I am working on getting FreeGLUT to build on OSX and am running into many instances of the same problem. Many of the functions exist only in the .c files.

Here's an example

```
extern void fghRestoreState( void );

static void fghRestoreState( void ){...}
```

I have a limited understanding of C, but the compiler errors seem to make sense:

```
src/Common/freeglut_gamemode.c:252: error: static declaration of ‘fghRestoreState’ follows non-static declaration
src/Common/freeglut_gamemode.c:43: error: previous declaration of ‘fghRestoreState’ was here
```

My question is, is there any reason they set it up this way? Would it compile on other platforms correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyword `extern` in front of the function means **[external linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c)**.
It enables you to use functions defined in other **[Translation units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)** to your own source file.
In Simple words, It enables you to use the `fghRestoreState()` in another file which does not include the declaration of it.

Whereas, the keyword `static` implies an `Internal Linkage`, that is the function should be visible only in the file in which is it defined and declared.
In Simple words, it tells the compiler I will be using this function only in this source file so hide it from all the other files in my project.

The error since as stated above there is a conflict in using the two keywords together.
You cannot tell the compiler to enable all files to see this function(using `extern`) & again tell it, hide it from all other files(using `static`).

So choose the keyword as per your usage of the function.

Comment: That was my understanding, and so I couldn't understand why the library would have that code in the first place.

Is there any condition where this would make sense?

So far as I could tell there were no ifdefs or anything that would cause this to make sense.

Comment: @Kyle: Given my answer which your compiler verify's,I can't think of a reason,Why someone would do that.