# How to initialize a static variable with another static variable?

Tags: c++, global-variables, static-variables

Static1.hpp

```
#include <string>
class Static1
{
    public:
        static const std::string my_string;
};
```

Static1.cpp

```
#include "Static1.hpp"
const std::string Static1::my_string = "aaa";
```

Static2.hpp

```
#include <string>
class Static2
{
    public:
        static const std::string my_string;
};
```

Static2.cpp

```
#include "Static2.hpp"
const std::string Static2::my_string = Static1::my_string;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Static2.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main(argc int, char** argv)
{
     cout << to_string(Static2::my_string == "aaa") << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

If I put `add_executable(printMyString main.cpp Static2.cpp Static1.cpp)` in my CMakeLists.txt, I get

```
0
```

while `add_executable(printMyString main.cpp Static2.cpp Static1.cpp)` gives me the expected behavior of

```
1
```

To make my code easier to maintain (so that I don't need to keep track of the order I list my source files), is there any way I can ensure that I get the behavior where `Static2::my_string == "aaa"`?

Comment: Having both static and const kind of defeats the purpose. I believe it is some C paradigm.

Comment: You might want to read about the "static initialization order fiasco".

Comment: do you really need to static variables with the same value (i mean they are const anyhow) ?

Comment: I've never liked `static const std::string`, which requires an allocation. Just use `static const char* const`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are experiencing effects of a [`static` initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

The usual work-around is to substitute your static variables with functions that have a static variable in the scope, initialize, and return it.

---

Here is how it could be done for your example: <kbd>[**Live Example (order1)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TNpZ3XGpNtIlSTmD)</kbd>
<kbd>[**Live Example (order2)**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dH38LoJm9MWvfACY)</kbd>

```
class Static1
{
    public:
        static std::string my_string();
};
```

...

```
std::string Static1::my_string()
{
   static const std::string my_string = "aaa";
   return my_string;
}
```

...

```
class Static2
{
    public:
        static std::string my_string();
};
```

...

```
std::string Static2::my_string()
{
   static const std::string my_string = Static1::my_string();
   return my_string;
}
```

...

```
std::cout << std::to_string(Static2::my_string() == "aaa") << std::endl;
```

Comment: Snap! :-) (Same answer at the same time.)

Comment: @MartinBonner actually you were faster by 13s :-)

Comment: Cool, also works for global variables that depend on other global variables!  Side question, what was the design decision behind [construct on first use](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order-on-first-use) only applying to functions and not variables?