# Why do functions/objects inside anonymous namespace have external linkage?

Tags: c++

Why don't symbols (functions and variables) that are defined in an anonymous namespace have internal linkage as with static keyword? If a function is not visible/accessible outside, what is the reason to have external linkage?

Comment: **They don't** have external linkeage, but internal. What is your source?

Comment: The C++03 standard, probably.

Comment: @SteveJessop anonymous namespaces exist in C++03 too, and give internal linkeage.

Comment: @Luchian: that's not true. Compare 3.5/4 between C++03 and C++11.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In C++03, names with internal linkage were forbidden from being used as template arguments[*]. So, names of most things in unnamed namespaces had external linkage to allow their use with templates. You could explicitly give a name internal linkage in an unnamed namespace by declaring it `static`, same as in a named or global namespace.

Both things changed in C++11 -- names in unnamed namespaces have internal linkage by default (3.5/4), and names with internal linkage can be used as template arguments.

[*] for types, it must have external linkage. For objects and functions, it must have external linkage if its *address* is used as a template argument, although it's OK for example to use as a template argument the *value* of a const integer with internal linkage.

Comment: +1, Please, Can you add to the answer the paragraph number in the C++11 standard that say that the internal linkage is by default?