# Are objects in anonymous namespace implicitly static?

Tags: c++, c++11

From the C++11 standard point of view, is there a technical difference of object status/properties between:

```
namespace
{
   int foo;
   const int bar = 42;
}
```

and

```
namespace
{
   static int foo;
   static const bar = 42;
}
```

?

---

From questions and answers around here I was believing that objects in anonymous namespace were implicitly static, but someone tell me it's the linkage only that's internal, the compiler will not take the object as if it was marked static with implications like how it will implement object construction. So I need some details about what it really means, if there is a difference between with and without static in anonymous namespace.

Comment: Theoretically, `extern` variables declared in anonymous `namespace` is a **superior** alternative over a simple `static` variable. That's why the "static global variables" were deprecated before C++11. However "extern variables inside unnamed namespace" are not the exact **replacement** of the "static global variables", and they were brought back after C++11!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

C++11, 3.5/4:

> An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or indirectly
>   within an unnamed namespace has internal linkage. All other namespaces
>   have external linkage. A name having namespace scope that has not been
>   given internal linkage above has the same linkage as the enclosing
>   namespace if it is the name of — a variable ...

So in C++11 both of your `foo` objects have internal linkage. In C++03, the first one has external linkage.

Regardless of linkage, it has static storage duration.

I don't think there's any such thing in the standard as "take the object as if it was marked static", so I can't answer to that. If you find some text in the standard that refers to whether the object is "marked static" and doesn't refer specifically to either linkage or storage duration, then cite it and I can give you an opinion :-)

Comment: That's quite a welcome change from C++03. Just checked output of `nm` on my object files and symbols from unnamed namespaces do indeed have internal linkage.

Comment: In C++03, without the name of the namespace, how does one access it from other translation units?

Comment: @Chubsdad: a unique name is generated for each different translation unit, so you cannot actually access it. Therefore the linkage is quite... surprising.

Comment: @MatthieuM: Surprising until you realise that it's because it's not valid in C++03 to use the address of an object with internal linkage as a template parameter. Then it moves from surprising to annoying.

Comment: @SteveJessop I just added the case when the objects in anonymous namespace is const. I think it is equivalent code, but could you confirm (or refute) in your answer?

Comment: @Klaim: in both C++11 and C++03, the first `bar` has internal linkage. So adding `static` to the definition makes no difference. *Unless* there's code earlier in the TU that declares `bar` with `extern`. In that case the first `bar` has external linkage and the second `bar` is an error. The same caveat applies to `foo`, but I only just thought of it.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks! So it's exactly like I assumed.

Comment: @SteveJessop Would `function()` have internal linkage if written as `namespace a { namespace { function() { ... } } }`?

Answer (score 3):

There is a very big difference: with `static`, the name has internal linkage; without it, it has external linkage (but is in a namespace you can't cite in another translation unit).  The difference isn't always important, but it does come into play in a few cases: if you have a template with an `int*` parameter, for example, you cannot instantiate it on `&foo` if `foo` is declared `static`.

### EDIT:

As Steve Jessop has pointed out, this is only true in C++03.  C++11 does make a change here. Although I don't know why; I find the C++03 specification more coherent—the namespace something is in shouldn't affect linkage.

Comment: You mean, in C++03 only right? If this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832940/why-do-functions-objects-inside-anonymous-namespace-have-external-linkage is correct, then it's external linkage in C++11 (I should mark this question C++11)

Comment: The linkage doesn't change.  On the other hand, I think C++11 does allow symbols with external linkage to be used as template arguments.  (C++03 definitely doesn't, and I've had to mark `const` variables explicitly `extern` in order to use them.)

Comment: But on reading Steve Jessop's answer, it looks like they did change this in C++11.  (In practice, because you can use names with internal linkage as template arguments, I don't think it makes a difference.)

Comment: James, you may want to clarify this in your answer than in a comment.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Given the format (with comments in a smaller font), you're probably right.  I'll do so.  (I'm more used to the news group format, where you can't modify anything once it's posted, but follow-ups appear with equal weight, and not as something secondary.)