# Are static functions in C language really invisible?

Tags: c

I was told that a function defined as `static` in one `.c` file is not accessible from other files. But in the following program, I can access the `static void show()` function from another file. Is my understanding of `static` functions in C wrong?

a.h (first file):

```
static void show()
{
printf("I am in static show function in a.c");
}
```

b.c (another file):

```
#include"a.h"
void main()
{
show();
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be possible.  Can you post a short example?

Comment: You are not #including one .c file into another, are you?

Comment: obviously I am. How would you even access anything without including it in your file?

Comment: @NehaChoudhary By linking after the compile step.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remember that `#include`s work by copy-and-pasting the content of the included file.  So in your example, after the `#include` has been processed, you get this:

```
static void show()
{
printf("I am in static show function in a.c");
}

void main()
{
show();
}
```

So clearly `main` can see `show`.<sup>1</sup>

The solution is to **not** `#include` .c files.  In general, you should only `#include` header (.h) files.  Your static functions shouldn't be declared or defined in the header file, so `main` will not be able to see it.

---

<sub>1. However, you now actually have **two** definitions of the `show` function, one in `a.c` and one in `b.c`.  For `static` functions, this isn't a problem, but for non-`static` functions you would get a linker error.</sub>

Comment: It is happening in the case of header files also. 
May be it true that static function are invisible. But can you give me any code-example so that I can understand it clearly. becuz I cant find a good answer on google also.

Comment: @NehaChoudhary: Your header files shouldn't list any `static` functions.  Please edit your question to include an example of your header file.

Comment: @NehaChoudhary: First of all, `static` functions shouldn't be defined in the header file. Secondly, even if they were, it wouldn't work, if you tried using them you'd get an error at link time.

Comment: @NehaChoudhary: Ok, I've seen your updated question.  The problem is that you are defining a function in your header file, which you shouldn't do.  Function definitions go in source files.  You compile each source file separately, and then combine the results with the linker.  If you tell us what tools you're using to compile, we can tell you how to do that.

Comment: @houbysoft I am not getting any linker error. I am getting correct answer. And I don't see any difference in static and non static function in c then why they are there in the language?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I am using turbo C++ compiler with a DOSBOX. :P

Comment: @NehaChoudhary: Hmm, unfortunately I don't know anything about TCC.  I would suggest going through the manual, and finding how to link multiple object files together.

Comment: @NehaChoudhary: Strongly reccomend you to move on to a more mainstream and standard adhering compiler like gcc or msvc instead of the age old Turbo C.

Comment: @Als yes I'll do that. Thanks

Comment: @NehaChoudhary: you do not seem to understand the purpose of separate `.c` and `.h` files, and compiling each separately. What you're doing (compiling everything as though it was a single `.c` file) is just not going to work when you move to a more serious project.

Comment: @NehaChoudhary: (which is why you're not getting the linker error I mentioned. Please read an introductory C tutorial where things like the preprocessor, compiling, and linking are explained.)

Answer (score 6):

`static` keyword changes the linkage specification to ***[Internal Linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c)***.
A function marked as `static` will only be *visible* in that ***[Translation Unit(TU)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)***.

Perhaps, You have same named symbols available in that particular TU, where you access the function. The how part of it can be only answered after you show us the code.

**EDIT:**
When you define a `static` function in header file, A copy of the same function gets created in every Translation Unit where you include it.Each instance of such a function is treated as a separate function(*address of each function is different*) and each instance of these functions have their own copies of `static` local variables & string literals.

Clearly, this will work but this might as well increase the size of your generated binary.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but it's not quite accurate to say that the static function is not accessible from another file.  It is possible to access the function through a function pointer.  It would be more accurate to say that the *name* of the function is not accessible in another translation unit.

Remember that converting C source code to an executable program consists of conceptual stages, including:

1. preprocessing (in which `#include` directives are replaced with the contents of the included file
2. compilation (which processes one translation unit at a time)
3. linking (in which the translation units are put together into the final program)

Suppose we have three files.  `foo.h`:

```
typedef void (*void_function_p)(void);

extern void_function_p foo(void);
```

`foo.c`:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static void baz(void) {
    printf("worked!\n");
}

void_function_p foo(void) {
    return baz;
}
```

`bar.c`:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    (*foo())();
    return 0;
}
```

This program compiles and prints "worked!" when it runs.

There are two translation units here.  One is the code in the preprocessed `foo.c` (which, because of how `#include` works also includes the code in `foo.h` and `stdio.h`).  The other is the code in the preprocessed `bar.c` (which, again, has its own copy of the code in `foo.h` and `stdio.h`).

By having the function `foo` return a pointer to the static function `baz`, we are able to call `baz` from the `main` function.

Now, consider what happens if we modify `main` to look like this:

```
int main(void) {
    (*foo())();
    baz();
    return 0;
}
```

This code will result in a linker error because the name `baz` in this translation unit cannot be linked to the definition of `baz` in the other translation unit.

This is the first advantage of static functions: another programmer cannot accidentally access our `baz` function from another translation unit.

Now, consider what happens if we modify `bar.c` to look like this:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static void baz(void) {
        printf("still works!");
}

int main() {
        (*foo())();
        baz();
        return 0;
}
```

This code will compile, and print "worked!" followed by "still works!"

This is the second advantage of static functions: we've defined two functions (in different translation units) with the same name.

If you try to put both static definitions in the same translation unit, you will get a compiler error about defining `baz` twice.

As a final note, if you take the program as it now stands and remove all the `static`s, it will result in a linker error because `baz` has been defined twice (with external linkage), which is not permitted.